# Как картинку поставить сразу по центру?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' viewBox='0 0 400 400' style='border: 1px solid black;';>
    <image 
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUSEhMWFhUWGB0bGRgYGCAgHhghGhsfHh0d
      ICEkHTQgIxolIB0dIzEiJiotLi4vHyAzOTMsNygtLisBCgoKBQUFDgUFDisZExkrKysrKysrKysr
      KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrK//AABEIAPQAzwMBIgACEQED
      EQH/xAAcAAACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgQFBwMCAQj/xABAEAACAgEDAgUDAgQEBQMCBwABAgMR
      BAASIQUxBhMiQVEHMmEUQiNScYEzYnKRFSSCobEWQ5JEUzRjc5OiwcL/xAAUAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      AAAAAAAA/8QAFBEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A3HRo15kkCgsxAAFkngAD
      uT+NASOFBJIAHJJNAaW28YpIxXDgmzKsF4QoiBHt5sjqjH/QWr311Z0nByMkquMLaNH4DBRfmyA/
      gEqvsPUefto+meK8nJG/Cx90BJ2uSq0AimgpIO4ndVgjnv7aC9j6nnEm8FQoFg/qVs/itlWP61+d
      ff8A1QEr9Ri5MFmtzRh1HJHLRMwA/JocjtqDNjdUbcwlxlsMQKZl/lC9t1UN3HZr7jjVIcjqmCcd
      N8WTC8ipGSwV2O2QlTfG0qNy0SQVAPBJAPvTepQ5CCSCVJUPZkYMP6WPf8al6TMHrWLLMUCnGyw4
      UgJyfSWBcgbWiO1qLd/SRRZdWb+IvIZUzlEO5tqTA3C59huPKMR+1wBfAZtBf6+68bxV2K737f11
      Eyur48ZKyTRoQASGcAgE0CeeBfF6Cbr7pcfxx08f/VR9yOD7gla/PIrj5HyNRovqJgFipkda93jZ
      QeL4sWT7VXfjQNejSlj/AFCxHoVMCzMEBha22tQI47HuNdW+oOADtaV1amO1opAfS20CivDN3APJ
      HOgaNfdLuN41wXUMZ1S13U/G0fLeyj+p1Z9P61jz35M8clBSQjgkBuVJF3z7fOgn6NfL1D6t1JYI
      97BmJIVEQW0jN9qqLqz8kgAWSQASAlu4AJJoDkk+2qT/ANWYzf4JfI5I/wCXjaRQR3BdRsB/BYap
      +sw8ed1SQGI/bhR8pdEnefumYAE1QXg+ljR1Mh6jkyenFxhBEgABnpO4PAQWwVeDyFsj450FjP17
      Ym9sXKrvSxhmH/SrFv8AYa6dI8QY2SWWGUMy/chBV1vtuRgHH9xqsimzJGRkysdVddyJ5DNuF3Zb
      zVPYiqA97vXPrCt9+biq6xi1ngc74+AGbna6Dkn0lqA5Oga9GlnC6i2PLHFLL5uPkf8A4fIJBIY2
      RE5Ao2vKP70QeaLMo0H3Ro0aA1TdZBllixefLa5JvgovAjPN+t2H4KpID31c6qseZf1c687lihJ+
      KLTVX9w3/bQJ3iDzepZy4cZYYUaMchl43mhUYNcGmFEMLUtY7Ex/H3VYzhw48BeDc9BgTGU8k/bd
      cOwFgHvx86leDeuBEy2jiMhbLFKnc70hUk/i2BvjufjUrqOXFkwKZgYcgG9u1WZK9YR1PBW+KPBI
      /Ogzbw34uORKIMTJnhd5ZGRJyHDbkYgBwvpIbtuse5vgaeesNky9Mjy5PU2PIk8ax+nzF2UNwIIt
      Wc+ngUtXR1lni76bz46nKikWSN3NMlkDg8E0CHLDaARRJAu+7X4P8TtJ0/MBWt8Duu77dyEiWieA
      N0iEDmix4AAACf02AdRhhlx5fJlVJB6gpKeXsBVyDT7GKvGCVq+extu8I9SXJibEmqVVUKHN+tVA
      5s8k8in43H1Ditfn3ovjDJwiFQC9xc7qNmSt1dwAwAFD3AJ7ad8XxLGcleoY8U/kD9gYtclD+GFV
      bJ3bT62JI2AFV40Fv4y8PbZjjiTZI4JiQGQR5MQHqBjRgDNGB2FB1sbbo6T8bqjYzmB8TGmmWQE2
      N5kUrasoYta0A1rVqea761vPhy84YUwxxjvE4d2kbbQaPlFtN/3kckD7PyNcOndB6bEWSZIcuZQq
      nbCCsaADy0okiwouyS1A8gUNBF8M+Ks3JjEiYw8sLxtXgN+0faOO4bb2aOgBuGrzp3U+p7yJsJCi
      tQIkAZgRdgbKCi6FsDY51Ki6/JOTHiQEKHCGRiFABXcSoo/gA1RN6D1fKWRoP+XlkUK1AsvpY16u
      +1uD3FHj+hDhmJ1OdFAbyDbBvLRLoggfdIaK/I96P+XXSFc+OBA7ozIV3Ewm3AIsErI9Ai+VU1a8
      UDr7/wAay3yWxkWBZI4g7qXLD1sKo0DYAYE0ByD70JnTsLPVR5uXDKaP/wBOVsk2ORJ2A47fnQV8
      Xidl8wNBI2wDjau667bQdxB9jsHcaqPEXWOmPLFvhk89wNkkKVLGSxCeocAny+Ae1L8jTRJDllqk
      jxZ4yaF7kZRXJNqwYk/G2tUWXgwTMUkTJxJUHD0XRgD6SG9S+kgkKaI445rQLK9ViJjHTeqZEjIo
      fyZv4kchBvy3kNMp+eSFAuvY2fgrNyMhsrqszCYInlwBCVjbYCZGjVjQF2oZuT6vVR1U9Z8Evh4u
      SYopMiJ02xrAdpiVyDM2w2dzgbSQT6eKA4FZ4z8WQ4/R8HHxZNzyIHIBHpoW4cKfSd7EFBQsEdgQ
      QbumEZE7LlGTzHNxurgpjgtIPJu+X9DAsRQ3KBR7tPVOlwvLEhbYCVBQcBgvqVeD7iKj34StY39D
      hHJvWebaqSxtGm8je4YgBlH3Lb2L9wP5TUz6g+Nf03U4ijb3hY71IICEbk45ADPGQb7C+3J0HXxj
      4/OHkoIwQ0S0Er0OC7BmB+GXbx7FSPY6ufpp9Tf1Ui4kik+n7278XbN82So/v/vlHjuNZ85fLCKZ
      I0fh7UeYodVscDhgo4F+knkkmT4Y6a/T8hJ8v+EpVglAPvYEBl4JUHaSwLWCK+4HQbh1bAByGwWW
      T9HkJe7b6YZSf4YiYfaRs30ftIWuDww+F+oPLDUtefCximr+dKth8B1KuPw41n3hLxAep4ct+mWH
      fLDRLS7hwr7VO4i2rtyWofbyz+Es7dMjFucvFVyAD/i4zeVMST6r9cS88+jQOOjRo0BqkmqPNLEn
      +NjEe9fwHJ/+RExodyFPxq71T+JpBGiTFq8mQP78iiHH/wC2XIHyB+NBmvgrrHk/qcaLf5s+e4O5
      BuQPEu5/TwGsbvg0SLrXLqf1AxMYyDGVJ5xEUaVuTMVkb1c8FQd7UPmhqP49wzhZxmiRRFkEMKUl
      S4o+oE7drAMpCsDZQ0KBOJZLAudvaz2uv7Wbr350GudD+o0M2TKssYxY8gfw2sGOP+GyMZV+1178
      Vya+bCnFYy5IsNvQ908bErCHXewUjkLXoZvYbxqH4P8ABc/UHZYwRW0iwQCG/cWqgq8E+5H2gmtb
      t4a8IdPxKjxoUyZgw3PJ2Thhu3BCoPBFDk3zoFHwh9LVmTzchPLCk0zcpIm4uGWMi1WmAtj+3lTZ
      Bb+g4uCkixdLxY5TGOcorujUjuol93uiQl1+NMjeH/NmaXJfzUKBFxyP4S83ZB+979zX9NSeodUg
      xFUSEIvZQFPNeygDv+BoIr9BaZQMuYy9iYwqCMMrBgQNpawR7sf/ABXmTrOBiu0KPEsjEsYogCxP
      YkqvayANzUL99RMeDKzhunvFxm5WFSDLIp5/inlVB/lQ3+R20xYOBFCoSKNY1HsoAH/bQKXVeqdS
      djHhYIiBNmWdlHJHPoWwfm93tz35Vk6d1LAyz1DNdcgSAx0nOwMQdgWgKO0EV/m43PzqfVOopjxt
      LIaVa9wLJNAckCyTrLvFXi6bP8zEw8acPtopJtQsCfvHNlQedyk/bYrgkJOFg5GTkyzrPGvm+SjN
      GhZSQjBw4sbuU20TQ5+a02weCoaIefKcH2/UOgHayBGVHNe9/A41l+ZjZ3Soi8sKMsroZS0xtyFE
      e0ejaC1bm5vki6HOhdL8dMU8zKwZ8eLbuEqgyIF27qalDq1e20i+LsgaCwzfDswAONmTowAAEj70
      r82pYmuOT+TZ51E/9RTYsezqUEjHcV82CFnjdaHqIXcVBJIpqPB47W1YeUkqLJGwZHUMpHuCLB11
      I0C7i4O2Pf06ZdlWkLcw/NChujHsNvA/lPbSh4x8N4nVT5IQY/UI4y2x0K2ARxuHpZLNbl3VuHa9
      WmdkRdFfduUYuTMaj2hTEzCyVoeoHk+rkcAauuv+HsbqUcUnmOCltDNBJRUsByCOD2GgzbBxh0JH
      3YXmNYIyCxrkcrewKHqyCC1AOePtbIfFXV3y8uXJcU0jX/YABbri9oFkcE6/SvTJcqGdMLqQhyIp
      A3k5RABdwL8tozYDld9UeQp781V+NfpJh5EbPjR+TMB6QlBWr2NjjjgdgKGgyb6cYeY+S2XHuMoB
      jjZxuDSFAFVy3IUKRbewoWCRpw+puNiRQpjMCzxRqHmpd0gReWJANuXAQluQTXdhdn03qUHSopjF
      jEzK3rTlTsA3GhbMh27j3K+kleONYt4l6/LlSvJIxYsxO4/cV4Cqa4obb7Dkk/0DSPoN1mONpInk
      Kny2YfCnuXqqZqAFmyKod9aP4PFjBYgk7cv1N9zB5FbeeBy/pY0OC1cVrB/plKUyJZAoOzHc8mqJ
      Kop7E/c69gT8CwCP0V0jp4XJgROI8PE8sgDgtMYyB/VVhuv/AMxdA0aNGjQGqbxhlRx4cxlIClGH
      Ivkqa4/qPkf1GrnSj47gOQ+JhFVMWRNcoN3shBkYcdgdoUm/31XN6BS6TgplYOL0zqclSTQibGkQ
      kED2js8F0Ujjmx7WtlQX6RSp1GPGZkeJwWDoxtUTjfIhHckgUDRN0aurzxl02XP6qkMUb+TjbY1A
      9Pllh/iAKVYIm2+WBvZXDAF36fjFsg40LtIqKq5mWWPmSMq+iEOOxG7cwX7Q3FFidBK6NgI6tFAD
      DDE5jkKrTzlBt5bbW38gk+3pI0z40CxoEUUo7DXqGIIoRQAqigB2AHYaS+rZrZ2Q2LhEbVDJkZQd
      x5DC6VArDdJff2Fgm+RoIPVvEGVLlGDBebzGC2pWF4YgTRkLLzXypcN8KfZtx+mCACV/MyZQKMjU
      W/6V4Cj8KL/rqr6jPjdKhbyYmaWZidqnc8jn9zs7dvyx+APjVR0Lq/UMlyuQVxowCTyjM1EekbWD
      Ka5uv78aBlj6vlOOMNoiGAuaSOms1xtcmvyRfI4PbXy+ocKGxd3c2X3BTde1bv8ANVcfb7arer9V
      ggDA55283HMokRuLKk7d/b2DEj4OufR+qQ5wMZYSopK70cM0RKE0zjvGwHpc8mgGG7uFvi+HyziX
      LlGS6uWiBjVUi7gbV92AP3E2fx21Afw/kQ5j50UkTBlp4fLZb+WVvMIEhoDtRr25Jm+FOhT4plWX
      KeeMlRCr1/CRQaHA5a2ok9wq/Grbqilo3RX2O6sqH4Yg1X59/wC2gVesdIOfkY7OUUYyCVed4Mrg
      fsIFhBtYMT+4WNN2HE6oFkfzGA5agL/sOBpb8KzASy7yA0seO6j9wVoa2V3oGN2/6j8aajoFTL6R
      CrMcHJXGn3kBVYGNnFsVeK65s2Fo8k9+dTMXqmWm4ZGLe2gHhN+ZwSSEslR2A3NzzyOAQ9DxcYvk
      x4oeYsz2qAyMzftBPYe3JAHJPudcUy+oSRgLDDEzH73lsBSL4VVO4+3cD3s86D7m9TMhVJsCXyHN
      OZEjcDjglQ5IF1zRP499UEXQpMCVn6fMrRsLlgkA3KLsNGFQFmrgK3yeb0wT9JznKt+tCU1kLH6S
      Pfi771QJbtyWutUfVpOqYiqWmXMZm4TyBfb9qIu40edxYAX/AG0DMMqKWOPz1jdXI2tQKbh24PKt
      345rteoBmnw5iGWSbDZbDglngYdwwPeKuQQbHYg99U3SPH+AI3TJdUcOyyfwCqFgQHJpmUephyx9
      9NGMiSESY8xH+TduWv8ATu4/t/toOHVeh4uequ6Hcv2SbKYAj23LTKb7EEf31gH1D+muVhkz+mSN
      5FW0WqLDg17AsK59yBzev0KmIiHbAFhk5YIC3ltd36QQps8kgWO+l7rwbKWDzP4BZ/LyMfeLaxa9
      12sAFZgwH7e+0NoMy+lHhZopP1eRuSOMXKjKw3A/4SAVbSM4Vtvatv3F+Nn8GufLkMqlMmSRpZka
      tyl+EHBIIEaooYHnb7GxrMsiDMxOsYUOQ6nESceXtQKjGQFQ8igczbqUPzRHFXrVfEI8sx5Qbb5J
      PmcgBo2BDBuOwNOK/l/NELrRrzGwIsGweQR769aA1n/WJ95zOpRNIf08UmNEoQN69w810HuNyhOP
      5Xu+Kec8uI3Mdb9p27u11xf4vWVLPNkdGwMXaY8jKm8tQj7aVGdpJuCLAVS/+oqefcPHhhTgdPyM
      pFByp2SFb9Cyuppq3AMSJHkU7gDa0PSFOnLwjtxoHQi1iDNPkFlCtL/7ijntHW0k0BtA9jXrxL0g
      LFF5TbWhASBAF+8qUU7iL4vdwR27jXKboilcfpuwPj7d+Qd3qcpRUMKsq7gk3Vha5FjQdZepGXD/
      AFOXux4258sMNwXd6SzniyKY1SgXyQL0nDx5BA8mF0fEaed2DWlFXJNO70eCKHJruLrVn4j6ZldS
      lWGCcx46F1mlUgofVRiWiNzrXulL2JPILN0rpOJ0rGIjTaossQtySHv7ep29gvJ7AaBN6B9O5Z2G
      T1Mb52WmWUiTyxdhEt245PqLcX20z9d8L4/kFDkHGj4t7T2s/c4IX+q0eAb1Pws3MnjV/Jjxldbu
      Ry0qf1j8sLurn7+Pe+2uWRgYUNS5Lh2HPmzvdEVbD9ikVZ2gUBfYaDNs76ddGkdFGZllmXgqGkDf
      nd5RFe/cDVr0r6Tx4jpmdOy3dlU0km1kmB4ZCy1SsLF80aPtq78S+OGW/wBCq5IUje0bjanP7pWH
      lIQQeCWsfy3euWHl57F5CMMOfUiY058x9t7rB/huSaIB9rBZTzoLP6d9SnlSaPJUrJFJQUkEqrKK
      U1xYIb+1av8AxBFuxpl2O5MbUsZpyQLGw2Ke6o3wa1SeGpMd8ufJitWyYo96sCrB8curhlPKsokj
      BH5B7c6YuohzE/lf4mxtnNequOfbnQU/R5Q+QHUgocSIqeLcOWN/7Bf63+NWHiGRhjyiNgsjKUjJ
      PZ3G1T/YkH+2qXw5NPJNG5+z9IizCx6ZVY8D392/FVr54+nfytsSsXSOaYFULUY4yo7fuuQEC7te
      O2gxlmyOrdS/itOUT+GI4gQ/loe7n7UDcm2sk8Adjpww8THxHXy+nYkTKSIzJn3OeLoEAhXPq43j
      s1cacug+FoP0eMI5JETYJHMUhXzmkALM7D1MDbVzQ3fIFTsWeBV3YWJ5oB27oVjVe1EhmZQwAFWt
      /HsaCl6X4qZGIaCQqar/AJpXBPvtMxVjwbIu6HA+WjB65DKxjBZXH7ZEZb9vSSNrj8oSPzrnk5rF
      fVhTP/l/gmvzzLX/APeqGHwqQgXE8uOBSP8Al5oZSD23A3LtBPPrCHv71yDTldKgkUJJDE6qbVWR
      SAfkAigfzpJ6n9OYse8rp26HIjJdRGAfMJ/YVZgmyuAvpqyb5vXOPrLYbyCKJztb+PCxBMAHZw5Y
      M0DWSHpq7EKQQH7AzEmjWRCCrCwRoFnpniWOd0w8uGTHyim7bLsG4gd42DEMff03XvWuPXcGeVJP
      LUHKhG0MaJkjJ3xuOKEiOoYEqaKsADu1Zdd8M471OPMimiB2Swkl0vvS8hl5spRuux1Q+G+sSvB+
      sndJHxjLCzoVHngfbYBIDEhGFGqY8aDn4mhOf0XzZQgyYU3uV7xSRH+KAV3FSCp4FngCtXHg/PHU
      +mKclFfzEKScWslCtw/r8ftYEdxrlPFGZpYUljVOpRPQQAkSom2Rt1bWBQrwfdPyarPo3G+PDldP
      kfc+JkEAEAEJIoZTwexbeRoGDwB1Ey4mxozG2O7Y7KRX+EdoNXxa7TXsSQOKOmXWd9MysiHr+VCI
      R5M8UchYEi9gCbwD6d3q2sBRISxZFa0TQVHi7NMOFkSL94ifYKu3IpBXuSxAr86VfA+E0mbNOxGz
      EiTDhVWBUEKrStQJUN9osUasECtXH1KgeXAeGNFZ5XjjG79pZwA4/wAynkfBo+2jrhODhpFiAB2Z
      Yo93O55DQJJYGyx3FqagCaOg+YrjKzWmcMFwdyItWC8gG5yRxvVRtCgWoc2bYqsvoHTlIyJ3jeN8
      uQmRWNGkHlJVGwCihu4Nse3YLXUxNiDF6fi5AR2QvMwCDaoa5JgzggFnaub7335079JkBhQhmYV6
      Xc2zgcBzxXq7/wBCNB2VI4Y6AVI0XsBQUAf+NLnTsig3UskOvm7EhiYHdErMFRdt0JJGZb7d1BNL
      xa5eOMgI4n/ghg/8Mkb9p7F1blLHK1R5B1AyOombLigVSI4mZ5mZRRIA8kKb/czBgR/LX40Fp1Tq
      cUEZaZlXj7SRbfgD3PtpGlSbqUpghXGhixqEs3kiWpWCsUg3eiwppnZfccc0Pf1DzMXAVskTVlbS
      oV55S7K5ukXedtsByoFD3A41UfRqfJ/SP5ZEhnmaQku22ANd2zKd0pPO0A+xYixoGWb6eQSNuycr
      JmaiKaRUUX8LGqir9jY5Os+8aeCsjEljycWMPEiX5sLLGybBd8jaKUcE7rI73V8et4GfPmSLJkSr
      5TgGLF375E/dIOdzutrZo8H0jaKFflQZGTGcPIyp8bZIP4ckfpYTSqp3lO1OUu/TZWlXmg1jwp1e
      GSaMOyiebGhyQCNrSM6vHI1dr2pHaj4Hxq98SdVWJCl07KfUTSxjsXZjwAOSBdtVD3rL/HXTMpIc
      CXDJ/ULlSJERttQP4Ua7SOwSMbvYHcT308dBwVy5WyMomVoajjjYUilRteUJVFnYNRP7QCK3aCv6
      Z4gTHyESQi57O1RR52BuP8rigPcOdt+7lYSZmkZR5m2OME96BY/3JJ/2Gq7xn4Wjz4fLc0Vsq1Dg
      kfJFjkA2tHj+oOU53U87J6vj9Kn3BIWNPQ81l2FhIzAbSQApsAAlboXWgkeJusHExmxCGZFmnCRc
      lHVZSW8wjnyo1dFC9rBuwK1beGEzuowIY+o+RsVVH6aEFEKDszEhWa+6xihYBJFar/qLhFIJI5F9
      afqwsinuspXIUcm91KynnsG77hpZw/FUjpHix5rYeNDGFJjpQXCFmRHoAWQfU7FmY8WNA+9R6/1X
      pOwZZjzYGavNRSstlgKI+yzYoWPf4GnDwj4xx+oIzQbxt4ZXAUg+4q/b39tZ94Y6vkODh5AbLx5o
      0G3IZfMVpUEixswo8qym6JBI7c1x8BZawdaaK2jSdGTyPMDsskYsbxQIAQMAxF8C+/Iaf1PoiFxk
      RRKMhLKtwu78OdptT7+/J5Gk/pufJFKrRr5MOQ1SRFfLMcpPOyyybiRYv0uCaIqtaTrD/FeZjx9R
      lwcnzFgyNu5j5YALGtysq/tNGpBX3ggbiWDTs3rz4ssceUlxSsqR5Cdg7GlSVO6WeA4JBPfbxa/1
      pIMDqKzsrCLMNTNuIRDsKg7QKa+AQe3DEjbqzxcUZPTJ8PczyRiTHclqPmRigQeSAfS4BugwHtqm
      g6kuf0PdM9MIwfNVg3lso3JKxVgQQw2seKYMTQ5AdOsZkGN5cOBW/DH6po46KvEz7Zx/q2OzivcC
      tc/Ek8sUkHVun7ZIiduRCAA0glKC7/mWgRfYkkWGOvmB1NZcfp/UHBdEMsWTJIFLRK6sjXSLcYkV
      bauxs+51W+AMZt3UejyyIJIuYHjIO2N727Qb4QstXZXfV6Bm8Sbv+IdNn2lYTvVpd4X7kLKrKRfd
      RVfLA17uw0gdV6Qj9IYtGkk2MpkFIy/xcewfTZNkqR8MD2o6bfDk2/FhkpF3xq9IKUbwGof76CF4
      hxzJkYK8FFmaRlJ77IX2mvfa7IfwaPtpf8U5izdUwMdRZhdppG3AgKqMAKDFlIarLKF7c+2rrqlD
      qmEa5aHIW6//AEmq7/BPb27+xUusM8mV1DMBowQpi+VZ/wDdYNJ3G3eU21V2T3ra2g+eHMn9RKsr
      xXkZc0m2TYgIx4CFaQOhG5PtRC1myCLAB02eNupfpsZEi8tWldII1Z9n3kClpT2W+1duOdVn08yE
      nlnyIYwuPEkeNjm73JFbMR8Dc1GrB2gCtpuD9WPExxo0kUgpG/s5DNMBcaelhaL97ggg+lfc0Hvq
      DSPgQYaACPJmbGYmgVjR2RqFDczqhJNe5q+LkQrK+bkSQp5i45jix1Z28oNtAlfhiisi7l7brJFc
      83HQukf8niGdSk0WMqm2ooxRfMO4DhiRRI7c1ql+neVL5+ZEhWbFD748gG7dvuTdt/i1x/E/Fc+w
      UP1QgXJzMfFyXlWNiXEZZNr+UrHam31CVwdu5yBRoc3ph8B9bafp0YheFZlRW2sQBEhc8bV7Rqql
      V5s7RZB51BkzD/xRvOkQHHxnKMzt5Yd6G6RqCxp+1QByd3crqp8B4/6Jsbcf4crzYzeknzTuMsUi
      7V5j2s9sxIAHBrQWvU8nGn8iXPWWDzmRFLQq0MjKW2Mu5CyF1ojdRraP2mpv/BlRoY4oyuQxWwoQ
      COMEbpXA4ogFFUkn1cdmIZHx4MmVWdopRCwaJAwYKxX7yP5xbBfgWe54j53WmETOlF5W246qNzOB
      QL7eCQPU/HG0D50EDosJGZl4zRyMtiXz2YEDzvuRbO4Kdm2lFUvezy0Y2NHCm1AFUWT/AOST8k9y
      TydVPSmb9fmKQa2QFSfcVIP9rVv++rLrL1C/yw2D+rkKP+50EwHSZ4plgVhnUBPjF1RgaLKKEofj
      kKpdgp/lv+jmBpUbAhyIGicVT5TGqIY3LBJd+wEnb+mgjeJukwvI5PO5Szs5JA3JalfYbUgIBqxu
      J7nVJ0/wnOigRectxAVv2KdpO0MoAUP8HbYFcjTb03pxkjjZ23b4ow5vn/BdTXHcmS/76m9a6t5I
      XYBI5ZRsBsgOdu6hztB/8HQKPRxH03+JnFYS5PkL5rSFzsBfc22jMTdEk3fHN3m+e8efkzeVCsUu
      RkRujsHWVI1JjLKxBpn9J2jgc964c/G3iM5EKSQRSO5jiZREVLwmTckobv6l3IKI4YDtzpB8EYck
      qJlzr53mZqIRJ+8csx7fbe4/BIK9zRDZvAPVZp8BWMnmywyNGWNfxRGeLNn1FSPUP3f30vfU6FJY
      sXqcUd+VIVkDMY3KtaNHR9JbfwVbuRt5Bo3X0gwhHgEhSPMnlayKLAOUU/P2qO/Ng67+POjI+HLt
      U15iysEYAqwIBkW+NwFPtPpNG63E6Dj4H6qk0xkhMZiyII5AUNU8R8twVI4O3YO5IC0TQW6PoHSD
      D1TKwC/lwsjSwFG2vskbcy8inVZL72RRBtXI1cRxRYuZiRpQRpJE2If8OSSIswPF7D5Vrf8AMfYC
      q/x5054uo4mXFv5EnpX/AO5EvmgKD+6SNJE7gc37mwneJegvj9PyEizDEq75Ab2HZt9aWi8AHlSq
      8cLRHBUvESjH6h0bNx1ZBIsUUlEsmxwoRfTYFhm44ugQDRIdfqbjHI6cDGsbAvG22Tcu5W9O0MOU
      ZtwXceAC113Cx9W8aTbgyjHjXZPCBZJkQXXlsqEho91GwTyQK+QbPGStCRMkhRZLWVBQEp20m6Rr
      WOgKuhfa9TfAGG8WFHHLE0ciWrbq3PsJXeSCb3Vd+4o6ofqR1MIyq0xh2jeVZN6TIvLBaI2ydx6i
      AeORwwcegZ4nx4pl3U6ggsu0n817XoPPWXhhU5coUGFHp2NBQ1WL7Cyq86yUeItvQMzJi3rK87Hd
      I24q0kgX0N7lU7cnb3s1rTfG/TmnxJIwbFWU/wDuVyEJo+knuNpv41gPWZwOjLjShUeLPVSFkLlV
      EUnJ5PA3UAODRI0GpeAstMDon6h922i+/azA+kAEKBax2u0fNbiRuOl/wf0pupZ6Nkbmj6dZbgFJ
      MmaRpZQD22q7UB3pFvvpm8d4EkeFh+UgWKAxGVlcDaqbQqBTwUY8MxIocncLGjpn6fB6CJghdWhE
      77fTveQB/UUApdxCdq2gA8aCu+pfjNnhyocUboYAY8uQ8C3IURx8jc/Jujx/m7Fo+nPU45Ol4pUL
      FUQGw8UQCLo87W2lgfcc6WJMVcbw+4nu5o3lndogpUycUEIAEhtUQGvn2rXRMNcaXomFOkcgWOaW
      RuQqSRRLtkPsQLK23uQeKrQdcw5MXVsRpVXZN5i350lsFj3lnX/C2oNwCgAWw5PJ1mniSQHElTHl
      3pPnv5CIrKxEnBsA0VahQbkjmhY08+JvE8ydViEg3QNEISioxEfnFt1uaqTYEcir27RQ5Ok2TwfJ
      EuNDTi8oiwdtWwRdzD9+1T2s23psDkL3w6/M+TiwrjSyxlkKY4qHHicq8i2Axkf17VoliEBIAJ1p
      XRU2xrsCx+vyEo2IooAQwXjgEo392UntWlvrsITq8EcA2KuNHGy9owq5MbAKv4UP244q+Dq4kyZR
      hiRY0YvGW9QBBOQWkKMNx7/w097MgrjQe/p4Gc5WTITvlmYAXwER5PLodqpjz3Jv40wdYkFwKf3z
      KP8A4hn/AP8AGqnoOTDipKssqIqyBFZ2A37Y41NX3Jk3ji7Yn31Wdb8WoM3FCwZLxRli8qwybELo
      VU2QAas38A/1oHvSdgJIXlTiNUypeT7xyLIzH/SXojtyv4rV+OvY1gefHZBIG7mh3Nfyj57aWIM9
      WysiFzw+WYkN+xxA7AUL7MWF3fPPYaC2zc/9JsgjjLfwXfdXH8ERqAefuYEV+AfjS71bp4gzcvKQ
      rEYlimPw6mOZST8ASUx9uCSLN6nR47ZAVvMvzen0oBHDral7He/Mr441zhy453GW67o8nARPLkAK
      7jI1IR8sX2kdjQ0FX17DWF4mwQ4yOoZCs6bq8vegkZxxQ27CxH7jffVN4q6aLTBhilYJLL5YhZVu
      SaNyNxJACq6SPRPsq86lt1RsbEl67LUkk5UY0Yvau7cqcXx6SbA57/Nap/DfVv1WdD5qM+O00qR5
      VBWd5PUjkbPT2VPTXLC7NWGx+HIUXGiEYIXbdMKazy24Vw267Hzel7xbYOSgkCJJiyGRGApiqNtc
      GwQzAMCeeIu3YhnlTy4iF3cA8gWwvu35Pufc/k6R+pmSNcOXIkhyJXLQxzxowDLJDIS7KCVoBQe9
      EF+PgOvV8KLJfpmbDSSTzwuzj96pE70RdbtoK33/ANtW31GMi4ZmhK+ZCwdA3ALG0Xn25cH81XF6
      zvwJ1hpZul4USDy4GlnZxZUVG6MqntQeRuRxytAChpz+oP8AHaLHjkYS7tyrf8MsjIQj0LDMG/8A
      iWNGuAsPGSJF0mVZdtJCBzZXctbL/G8L8e2kn6rZhbM6WhK7ROnmKb4a0IraNwHq7g82nHp01/Ub
      JZlxMNNhmyZxSsTW2JS8hquV4VTY7NfBAIVPrXFG+V0+NfTOZUA9JIdGY0L7EK6jgg1vsdzYMv1D
      6MciXHVMgRESBirKjXwQoUPxbVVH0tto0Ty2dGxPLjCKGVQAFRgPTQo1tNBTV0OBZ9uAq+PcrGdh
      E8InlSMzxxUf43kuC6KQeXWr2jnuKIJBdMZ9yq3HIB4Njkex9x+dAu/UKedMRv0+/c3pPl/4gv3T
      1AkjnhQWPsPfWRdXjU+H5t8RZ45kPmsQWLmQK+5t5twCV9u/atfoMjSb0Dwz5U06GJDhkqUEoDO0
      gfcW57RhlBUfJuux0C91HNmm6ZmLNJG5x3Cq6ttClI4iQQDwRJu5PAAJ7Vp0z+kjLw0ijlZI5Cjl
      l9JKFt5A4sEg0DwV4PcaWuhxy4HUJ8XI9UXUZJJYpjR/iULiP/QLFgDihfJ136lkNidPlxVDA4Sx
      MG774VlHI5+7y0II9yO3NaD79WsNR007PT5RUxoE3fYQ3C3XCqSWPCrvP5GaQeJRN1vp7z5XnRRL
      6pm2Il7WZjx6QqtXck+m77a3jCmhyIkyAAySR2pcVaPz2PYMKNH8Xr87fVHw5jRBJsNZPLcvTsyh
      GVavykrcU3N9/Ykkiwd2g2XqvSE6pGwaMxRpKGhkZSC/80gX/N2ViO1kd71G610xWzsGJo2MInaU
      G+A0UACEjueRe7tf9eeHgTxfLJF05J4ywyYHqYG/XAWDBhVDcoBH53fGrvr5CZuFKzhQXkjCGhy0
      bMW3EX+wAAV3N3xoKnrmCv6yTJ/fJshjaxahfS20dyd0xu7HoA9wNevEHU4MSByCFSGVmIJ5by4S
      EoX7SmJFHyo9+dSM1FmyTsU7Y54o2NkAtuGRJtHbgpGCR3twe2lrxThifHxVnvacuXz/AE7WaJch
      2cfhRtDnnsprmtAjeAvGGFBkjKyopXnsrEsSKwjDWDZZ97SNuYlqsljd8a1g/VvpWzcZ3BHdDDJu
      u6qttX/f/wAaz7xl4O6m+YkWPCrYpP8ADVQgiRbIAYcdlon5+SdLvUvCEkfUWxH2M5KdvZXeNBRP
      H7uL9VGzz3Bn8efUvp+bEYhjzeYpqLIO1TET9xBDbh2rb+7+2pv0q8Sef5YkRDJh/dLwN6SKY1fn
      1B14U1wQR8DUL6c+Fuq4+aqTwkYyFlfeVKFSf2C+b79vz31Y4XhODHz8h0Ux1lLJGi8DyYUE0gof
      sLhQFP8AKtDQP/SYwr44NABMmMDuf8Va5+KTn540ieGkdukTxs1x4ucyxujcoiSAgkH2UsTz2Ug+
      2nrpkfly4ccpHmDGlYjeeDuh3muxFt9x5+O51UeFsJIun5izKqxvk5RlFighlZWN/AQXz8aCh8WQ
      rL1Tp/TEtYYB+orjhjIdi9q2itvbsffU3q3hpceSWdmZcdFeONFoJD5jecHAAsbZQlEG1KA9q1B6
      H1iKbrWLkxSB1fDMEjewdH4v4LHbXsdwA768fVrxdNEGxfKUASBmbcpDINjLQJ3br3Gq4IGgd4fG
      MDdOfOibzFjVvu9JZkHqHx7HkcfGse8eeL540mxw/lo/EcJi5VJAC0iuft/cgHwz/jTv4e6McvE6
      fHCGixI/VMnG8SKd4DAimjYkfkccUTWW/UbHfI6plABtquI0J4VdsfC9jSgKeB8+16Bt+hOVEqZB
      lOxF3FW3UUJAB4HNlT35+0/jWjeG8FZpJZ2laQSqjoSu0hSnprgEEbmaiLUuR7aUejeAGx4sWKMK
      ZSjTZBYUzAWFSvcDfVX3APbWpSSlYnnWMs/l7vLB5JVb2j8nt/toF/HgjbOysycgtiqqIhF+UoVm
      8xb93V2BI+CL4Oqvp8uHl9YmDFWaGOGWAFiGV2DeYyi/5ViDAWOB7k6idc8XvD1DHVDHPi5agekg
      uFfgFebO1ifTXYqO+rTw79PcSHGdIpC8r0f1JCmRHUCipq1IoWugj9W6bLJnqWjRytsv+pQdsi8i
      pCnobkXtU2KBV56dGVjUMu01yLv/ALgVfz/5PfSZ0PomZEYGzJhJMkrXIgNMpIT1f5nBU3xQSvbl
      80Bpb8V9DOVXmSzLDGpPlwGnkZrHJAulFVVfcxPYUya8TfaeCeDwDRPHtz30GcQ9LfNgk6fkSt5+
      K6yQylkMqKbEbOUahMpBuu4A55NNGPmLkQTgBTNCXhfzOwKtwzf5SAsntwR21V9V6bltPDNH5caY
      x3+Uiks60w2tJ2ZiCSEAoHkliV1W9X67j4edjZolrFy4G83i0A3K0biv3FpDfyC3xwFp4EyfPgmw
      5wsggYJXlFA8bKGQFSTY2kc3R/Pc0H1YxgcKYjb5i7PNcn0orMFWJKU29MaFcBmY0WW5ks8vT+pi
      Z/48HUCoaTb6omG5Y4xQAERLRqNx737knTrndP3sHoN5dskZ4UyVw7fNe3xZPJC0H5k8M+IngTyV
      engl8/HfcaDKr7onBP2Ot8KASzd+eNn8cypmdKg6gvpMfl5CtfEfYt7ckdq4N8fINL1bwMP1vlRr
      upIskttUecyySiZOB+5ZFFexYH5OpXheCWXoefjhVjeKXKRFT7BRL7VJHCbiQG7juCCBQNjYQxkw
      13Fz+o3ySAcO0wcM5HsGklFD2sew0reLZ5WjYQcvvmVChFhxksykXxZkSJCL5DsNXeLkfqOiGcDe
      WR50UuTsZZGljWxz/DIUV/krXnF6RBmozJKSksUrLtO1l/USxzxuLHDqy8NXpYfjQJXhfxSMiADL
      zBhRQtuMSsNx8lwQnrjsC9voBPwABxqk6711JOo+bflmbfIl2SCoiEG6qG1jjIx2kkb2XuL07Z3Q
      pWKrn9JXKkWNVOZA8ZZvyyOFth78H8fATF8QuJ4srFTB8nGDqX/SPGVBUFi0Ya2NC/SaBJ7DQMXX
      fqRjhIczEnZJpFHmwGQFE7XuXaW3/DKpHckc6++AMqbNyY8nIIT9R5gRRyTDCVZ+Tz/EkMYLVW2N
      lAFivOD0/Gynjy/+HzdQlkAPmPF+nxwORtVTwaNcvuu/u4oNPhzw/LDLL1DqMqK/lNFHGn2Y0W69
      ooAFqAHA9ve9BbeHyMnIysooQhC46Bh96RguZBzRVzKar2UXz2pegxN+jyMK7Zv1Cb+CylpJY08z
      2YnYvqod1BHvptlZcXE4basMQAZlsAKALYCuPc1XvrP/AAh1l/1MmQVZmng3hQoAZEyZXYxju/om
      9vUGUhgNy2FV9LvCL464+cm9yxEcsW3skhpm5PDxOBdftW+/GlXx5gyv1dTOC8KTRI1sWWjRUci/
      UvHvdGzwTrZJMw48eZ5KqBFOGYdtpkZJJCeOUZX337EuOKFLWP4XXNC/8QPlS5UwyFiUj0qpdkS6
      oybSQexrcR2Ogu/DHiaNYsmaQ7Yo9hU0b2iK2Ug9njKspHel550leG+jrN1Jn3ncyNLFu7MSoUgN
      Xbbtb5P9jq88WlZc/G6XHGed7vJfDK8MkcisRzvAZWs9yR7kW3dLxv0eMIiY2eINJ25ZAeT/AKqO
      2+3A4A4AXZiV2SQHlSaI9weCP6X/ANwNY94x+pr4E0kWIgkikaRgXsGN1kdJQvyhdSwHBFmjRG3Q
      cfrixYmRIx5ikmPB/a0rFG59trD/AGPxr8r5TmbzciR7laQs3AFlySTQHANk8AAUR7jQbl9HPDOP
      lYU2VlQrJJkyyCz+1d1+jm0O6zYo8KfYa1uGIKABZoAWe5oVZ/Osu+i3UMkY2OjNFLjMGQNGfXDI
      NzhJBX8oPq/MYr3Oq6DnLEGq/Y2Ofca6aNGgNGjRoPh0m9OwoXlyMPJhj9YDxpZI8oHhe21XRm3F
      UNDep97Lnpb8S5qx5WDuFKZZA0hHpQGFwAW7As1AD3/20CrmROnT8jp8SzySwyquOZFZmChrSXhS
      dqMj7QQB6V7KQdOHgjrjZuFFkOmyRgVkWiNroxVxR57g65dT6SRn4+XCSGIaOcWaeII7Lx23CTbR
      4NMdYt4X8ay4vU2xllWPEbMd33MNoU7lb1GvTzu47lR37kN4x8TdPLOfdFhAI7hCxY/0Jav+m+eN
      K/hmMthdQhDGSQTZClWA77QFG1ftQgCl77a0wz+IonxZsnFdMgRoxqN15oE9yaHa+f7apMmV+ndE
      3KjmRIAW2jcwdx65DyLIZmc8i6/Ogzn6O9UyJvN6ZKzqhjEkSkfYjiy3PdaZWC1TFubFgsfRZYYV
      TGaGNrUviF3fzDDJyQGALMARbRiiP5aA1f4vTIYZH6xHRQ4UaxAitoAu2+FoR8nsN10BrL8HGfN6
      LOwAfIwcm4pFNOquyszWD9otjXYBfcqDoGrO/wCM4xWXZ+rxCppcSZhw3Y+rcWoVVDmh8m6Q9f6f
      u3T5PUYMhTwZMaJSm7gllSPa+6gNzergVWrbwR4ulkR4hIIs2KxKkikoxXgysopqcn1FOVb1EEMx
      0yjx7IvpyOmZMhqxJiKMiJ+O6uK78ijyPfvoKjC8cQfp2EM/UclxQUx4qjbQHsFVSvzZ9+/I1f8A
      S8XqOWIZp2SBFF+U8Su7sDauwIqNh8Kx+bB41xPjPIRVY9OGMjdv1EwRmJ5pIo43kd+b2hb0p+OP
      qMUWSLe1GiVNxySWOI1St8UNUzO58xuQAAbAMOD4gm6mz4eyMpG295kb0yiGRaj2kHaJJFZbsgqj
      1+LroeHG2HGkgMUsTjcoN+VKTtYKf5WNsPw4PHGsl8A+K1xcXLzZS36h3UKvZWC7Co/AoFQAKoV8
      aY/BviFEgME7eZaSy9Q3Ky7A/lRo17SGYKNu0EXTEdhYMvhbqiyvlPKojixgYZvMaw0flq6O1jt/
      iEj28w+2k7qmZkK7ywnZj4mZEGV2tkVpgFcH2sgowN2CCTd6ZvDYOB0SSecjzpo2lCseT/CCwx0f
      cRqi188cnvafT7oKRdPjOTbPktHM/mdw52mNf+kqtfnQefCHTpIJkbMdTk5CyyBTyyBSg2g/hGVT
      /pHfUTrniCCN2WeZRJEssPfl/wBQxEQIH7v4Y5/1HgarfqF1Bi+LsnEWWs08aOeAoZywJofaPJjV
      jXCyWe+qOTw0kmXjRPNHJ1GZn/USq5ZY0UsxVRQtnjYLbdgOPbQd4vBWVPBP1D9UYpG3oUFbWghb
      7bYgJKClhrAB5NWTrt0bwREMiV8rFaSCRV8qRSVeMURv8tDeyyDxZQ7DVeoPGUsbsnTYYlfGhCrk
      AMPQpHoj216u6s3alrvem3aO9c6CN0/HREGwJ6gCSgADGgN3HyANStGjQGjRo0Bo0aNAaTfqPhTz
      RLHijdOWUruJ2IFcWSB7sSBZ7LuIIo25a+VoFzwx1Veo4nmSRgW7I6bibMb0b4HpJW9p4ING7I1m
      H1X+m6RxNlwqzyMbkbcQq3uZm28mydsaqLstybrV/wBUfG6V1tcmR3SPLhfdfKLI0qW3wq1yT8n8
      60NGx82FW4lhYhhYNEowINH4ZQf7aD8w+CfEkuIs+NuYLNw8YQ79yMOATwtruuweFI4ux+ns3FGT
      jPExoTRFSVb+daNN/fvrBPrP4bWHJkzEsGRrdewO4lRR7+oIxP8AqGmv6R+PYI+nR487EzRyNHHG
      is7upIKmq4AL7e9AAaBvkwpJ+j+TMBG8iVIFb/NucA/BUN/bSD9NSuNkv02cV+ohQSKTySFeNloG
      r3k2Qfb451qPiqIsiLsZkVtzqvAYEFNjN7IQxLH+VT86y/q3S5YBj9X9JnRIpHUqQC2RKzEX91cl
      R8A8jQKP1H8POkwyY73Ozhn7bnjkkBJPZW2iMDtuJNc96fp31H6hFx5wcVRDKLP9WWnPxZbW4YCY
      /UunyyoA0bpIjqeWDbd0jX7Nvoj8c+4AxLxB4Oljm2qqkCBZyQeNjOVZz8BTwePa9BF6p45y5idr
      JDYAPkJsah2G/mSvxu5118FeGWzZAv3FroG79Hr/AP5Kjp7USvzrzgeGXMR3oqv5iqpNkgMWRrA4
      oEWD8j860jwi8WBGMgwlQ0nkbgeRcyxg8nt6ZAx72o+dBy8AfT5t8WXlMBjQtI+x2vYY/SoPttJO
      /d7BAPfUz6kdPSGsfHFPmTRQuwerijG9Vr4pwCb52/2F7jSNHG/T5pSpKNEHbhd1NGp/DPvgf82T
      8gI3T8uTP65gbuHgRDKNwovGx3lPwfSSp7euuKJDR/HXTv1WTj4SkbNhMoDUQm+NeDR9QsEe/b5v
      TFjwK4zIl9JDhRX7agjKEfFcEfkaRvE0D4nU5M13Z4Csch4soI5BvUEcUuwkg/IrlddPF3Vch+oH
      G6TkqJ5oFaQgKyqUcBSbUgWjmyBdKv8ATQVeN1JcmaScxMMhJFMTIOUOTAm6UA8ErHZYWSNikDvT
      10vwliYCCbdTq2+TIcgM59YO49gCJGFCgOPgag+CvCTQSvkZLlpEpYwDSRgxL5hFAbiSSu5roLQr
      Vf416vk5rvhdP8qRFSKSSWywO5yPLsAixSvdngHg8jQNHgNw+GkpRkaV5ZGDqVa5ZWc8HmuRX4rT
      FqF0cDyUK7trKGUMbKgiwt9+O3NnU3QGjRo0Bo0aNAaNGjQGjRo0EbNwlkBsANtIV6BZLHdbB599
      Jw6fP0mAGCWTIxkd3eOQbnRCvZXvhQwuyD3PzYetfGUEUeQfbQIvV48TrWJJFuLPENxRC3ok9aqT
      wN3KuAOR712Osh8SdBl6N1D9Sg3wRSRstmgzMhKpV87SDx7LXzrZup9GkxSr4cgQCNvSy2HaNmlV
      WPHBV5Rfft764fUfw0mViyMxBUP5hodvQsZIP4UE3oOf0u8VjPXJDkNIJNzDuNrrQ9q22rKB7gA/
      u0zeIenRSQTLKu9WC2n820ikH+o8f9Wvzd9OuuZGJ1KKBiwD5CRyx2ACwYxjdxztLGqNWAeaGv01
      HmJIQtEkO39vKaix/G6q97r4sBk/QOp/8O6lkYWW3l4sgOyuF3SKiFyP5f4dAntvB/fp4zumRLmY
      8WzcjYssLg8ho2KXuFc01f2dtKX1B8H5Gf1EmIfwRCFaQMBsewxHPJNCLtxV9jr5Ji9QyMCJgu3L
      wmjMJKsDMg2rbfuG5o5CR7jb7NoIvSujFQuNM1vFO4kJoEFJC4P+mWOVWAPAJHsOGbGx8afInwgF
      aISurqLoB03N343iWP299383PfDijy82Gdh6Mjp6OyezFj8/6X/7DXTpWEOn4r7yxnMkxB7tLTPN
      S+xYxKf7roK3xpkRxIssiLktDG8U9obBEZphwQrMHeieDdBhbWg/R/pc8jZWftDSiM+XzXmMCrOO
      3dvT6hyGPPuDd53g+fqLZjxZAjlEhSmvbMrxJR3A3yAa+4EbeODpgl6iIscSQxfp2SNysVBdk0QC
      yw8HafMQqygcEpu99BViWDq/6qfGMxRloxMvB2eUz7FHO5xa/k/B0xfSfwQmBj+a3qyJh62uxQPp
      Cf5SKPyeL7a94WXBjRfqV9OXPiqVgc0f4aBVG37hZ2KT/TXnpMOZnSO2S3lQpKV2RueWikApWFHb
      SG+P3mqINBy8aePBGuTj4+NNOyKUaSKmRC0bGyVJKsvHDAE8121efT/wxFgYiRRrTOqvKbJ3PsUM
      eew47du+rDo/h3GxS7Y8SxtISXYXb2S3qJPPJNX2s6tANAAa+6NGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDR
      o0aDzIgIIPYiv99I+FgvhIR/EmgLNHJBxSlyx8xeLKylgzAkhS5qgCA9a8uoIIPY8aDG+peDcPL6
      lDkiYojqzP5RFRyRgsTvII+4Emx/L86iw+Mo+m5075DStE8X8BLLH0KuzddeqQMzEnsT/toUPgmJ
      IcaFFRRG4abaoHn+n1Emu5cI/wD01YGlFvBEc2X1NHBcpGjQEgHymYyMFF9+FWjX2sR+dBqPT51l
      iVxVOtkfk/cD+bu9K3U5Hx8t2JeVp8eXyoVrbcZQBF4+4rVljVk1QOkvw712fp+bsy5T+jbGE6gi
      /L8+WMbQbohXfkj2vTL4Z8d4ufmoUPISVEU912kM8h4+1lVK+KIOg4eIetjpuFi58VTRrBHDGhBQ
      kMAUc8WPQOVr/wA659Dx8jMiyI2BBhMXlFjy5WIq/HsssTsm6+CW+Ob/AMfdJhyosfGkU+X50ZIU
      cBeVHb9oLLfwDrn1Hq8UMkE3KrHGVZQ3JUxMyqR7kNHQu+W476DxndVjhKxLSrNJuUnulJFtYf6X
      PIPZVb+WiseK+u4mbkQ4+4vu8l3WIF2jkjL2lLzuIej8bTdVrhJ4Yys9svLmPkSCOod/IWNrkKEA
      ghwCbN8WnwRpx8F+C4saAybSuTkKGmk/cC9F1X3UXf8AT80NBM6JiDKCZcsKoz0xUkMw2JsVdwFF
      QTI1jg2DpmA15hiCqFUAKoAAHYAcAD8a96A0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjR
      oDURcBBMZwKdkCNQHqCm1v39NtX+o6l6NAt+IPCmLO0MkmOsgitdnNbG5PpumpqaiPbjkDSL1LwD
      H0z/AJyB/wD2pIWUikUyQlFfvxbhAfy3fWvah9X6es8MkD/bIpU/3Hf+2gyYdZ6tkLGMaNfMErpA
      xUBGhDgCVg3Hp2XY+VIHOr/wf9OTFMuZlSPJkEHeGI2qQ9jaAK2mgf7D500eEoD+mg8wVLCjQkey
      lWCsO3I9ApvcUffV9oPhGvujRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDR
      o0aA0aNGg+Vr7o0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aD//Z
      "
           id="image18" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое это получить width и height этого изображения на javascript и присвоить во viewBox, делается это так

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("#svg");
let img = document.querySelector("#image");
let bx = img.getBBox();

svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + bx.width + " " + bx.height);
```

Другими словами получаем его размеры img.getBBox();

А потом присваиваем это во viewBox

Посмотреть можно здесь: [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyPLKKO?editors=1000)

Comment: можно еще размер картинки явно задать таким же как и viewbox

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я знаю - но мне кажется так чище без width height потому что так можно регулировать размер блоком ...div

Comment: не спорю, но тогда надо ждать загрузку и только потом считывать размер

Comment: да и особой рахницы нет, т.к. это svg и финальный размер определит его контейнер, и будет или не будет применятся upsampling/downsampling зависит от этого.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я делал на onload но тогда bx.width и bx.height не приходили

Comment: а можешь посмотреть какие значения размера картинки у тебя возвразаются в этом ответе? (я на мобиле)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  207x244

Answer (score 1):

Если картинка и контейнер имеет постоянные размеры можно задать viewBox="-97 -76 400 400".

viewBox задает размер области отрисовки.

Первые два числа — координаты X и Y верхнего левого угла масштабируемой области, два других — её ширина и высота. Значения задаются в пикселях, единицы измерения указывать не нужно.

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' viewBox='-97 -76 400 400' style='border: 1px solid black;';>
    <image 
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUSEhMWFhUWGB0bGRgYGCAgHhghGhsfHh0d
      ICEkHTQgIxolIB0dIzEiJiotLi4vHyAzOTMsNygtLisBCgoKBQUFDgUFDisZExkrKysrKysrKysr
      KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrK//AABEIAPQAzwMBIgACEQED
      EQH/xAAcAAACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgQFBwMCAQj/xABAEAACAgEDAgUDAgQEBQMCBwABAgMR
      BAASIQUxBhMiQVEHMmEUQiNScYEzYnKRFSSCobEWQ5JEUzRjc5OiwcL/xAAUAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      AAAAAAAA/8QAFBEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A3HRo15kkCgsxAAFkngAD
      uT+NASOFBJIAHJJNAaW28YpIxXDgmzKsF4QoiBHt5sjqjH/QWr311Z0nByMkquMLaNH4DBRfmyA/
      gEqvsPUefto+meK8nJG/Cx90BJ2uSq0AimgpIO4ndVgjnv7aC9j6nnEm8FQoFg/qVs/itlWP61+d
      ff8A1QEr9Ri5MFmtzRh1HJHLRMwA/JocjtqDNjdUbcwlxlsMQKZl/lC9t1UN3HZr7jjVIcjqmCcd
      N8WTC8ipGSwV2O2QlTfG0qNy0SQVAPBJAPvTepQ5CCSCVJUPZkYMP6WPf8al6TMHrWLLMUCnGyw4
      UgJyfSWBcgbWiO1qLd/SRRZdWb+IvIZUzlEO5tqTA3C59huPKMR+1wBfAZtBf6+68bxV2K737f11
      Eyur48ZKyTRoQASGcAgE0CeeBfF6Cbr7pcfxx08f/VR9yOD7gla/PIrj5HyNRovqJgFipkda93jZ
      QeL4sWT7VXfjQNejSlj/AFCxHoVMCzMEBha22tQI47HuNdW+oOADtaV1amO1opAfS20CivDN3APJ
      HOgaNfdLuN41wXUMZ1S13U/G0fLeyj+p1Z9P61jz35M8clBSQjgkBuVJF3z7fOgn6NfL1D6t1JYI
      97BmJIVEQW0jN9qqLqz8kgAWSQASAlu4AJJoDkk+2qT/ANWYzf4JfI5I/wCXjaRQR3BdRsB/BYap
      +sw8ed1SQGI/bhR8pdEnefumYAE1QXg+ljR1Mh6jkyenFxhBEgABnpO4PAQWwVeDyFsj450FjP17
      Ym9sXKrvSxhmH/SrFv8AYa6dI8QY2SWWGUMy/chBV1vtuRgHH9xqsimzJGRkysdVddyJ5DNuF3Zb
      zVPYiqA97vXPrCt9+biq6xi1ngc74+AGbna6Dkn0lqA5Oga9GlnC6i2PLHFLL5uPkf8A4fIJBIY2
      RE5Ao2vKP70QeaLMo0H3Ro0aA1TdZBllixefLa5JvgovAjPN+t2H4KpID31c6qseZf1c687lihJ+
      KLTVX9w3/bQJ3iDzepZy4cZYYUaMchl43mhUYNcGmFEMLUtY7Ex/H3VYzhw48BeDc9BgTGU8k/bd
      cOwFgHvx86leDeuBEy2jiMhbLFKnc70hUk/i2BvjufjUrqOXFkwKZgYcgG9u1WZK9YR1PBW+KPBI
      /Ogzbw34uORKIMTJnhd5ZGRJyHDbkYgBwvpIbtuse5vgaeesNky9Mjy5PU2PIk8ax+nzF2UNwIIt
      Wc+ngUtXR1lni76bz46nKikWSN3NMlkDg8E0CHLDaARRJAu+7X4P8TtJ0/MBWt8Duu77dyEiWieA
      N0iEDmix4AAACf02AdRhhlx5fJlVJB6gpKeXsBVyDT7GKvGCVq+extu8I9SXJibEmqVVUKHN+tVA
      5s8k8in43H1Ditfn3ovjDJwiFQC9xc7qNmSt1dwAwAFD3AJ7ad8XxLGcleoY8U/kD9gYtclD+GFV
      bJ3bT62JI2AFV40Fv4y8PbZjjiTZI4JiQGQR5MQHqBjRgDNGB2FB1sbbo6T8bqjYzmB8TGmmWQE2
      N5kUrasoYta0A1rVqea761vPhy84YUwxxjvE4d2kbbQaPlFtN/3kckD7PyNcOndB6bEWSZIcuZQq
      nbCCsaADy0okiwouyS1A8gUNBF8M+Ks3JjEiYw8sLxtXgN+0faOO4bb2aOgBuGrzp3U+p7yJsJCi
      tQIkAZgRdgbKCi6FsDY51Ki6/JOTHiQEKHCGRiFABXcSoo/gA1RN6D1fKWRoP+XlkUK1AsvpY16u
      +1uD3FHj+hDhmJ1OdFAbyDbBvLRLoggfdIaK/I96P+XXSFc+OBA7ozIV3Ewm3AIsErI9Ai+VU1a8
      UDr7/wAay3yWxkWBZI4g7qXLD1sKo0DYAYE0ByD70JnTsLPVR5uXDKaP/wBOVsk2ORJ2A47fnQV8
      Xidl8wNBI2wDjau667bQdxB9jsHcaqPEXWOmPLFvhk89wNkkKVLGSxCeocAny+Ae1L8jTRJDllqk
      jxZ4yaF7kZRXJNqwYk/G2tUWXgwTMUkTJxJUHD0XRgD6SG9S+kgkKaI445rQLK9ViJjHTeqZEjIo
      fyZv4kchBvy3kNMp+eSFAuvY2fgrNyMhsrqszCYInlwBCVjbYCZGjVjQF2oZuT6vVR1U9Z8Evh4u
      SYopMiJ02xrAdpiVyDM2w2dzgbSQT6eKA4FZ4z8WQ4/R8HHxZNzyIHIBHpoW4cKfSd7EFBQsEdgQ
      QbumEZE7LlGTzHNxurgpjgtIPJu+X9DAsRQ3KBR7tPVOlwvLEhbYCVBQcBgvqVeD7iKj34StY39D
      hHJvWebaqSxtGm8je4YgBlH3Lb2L9wP5TUz6g+Nf03U4ijb3hY71IICEbk45ADPGQb7C+3J0HXxj
      4/OHkoIwQ0S0Er0OC7BmB+GXbx7FSPY6ufpp9Tf1Ui4kik+n7278XbN82So/v/vlHjuNZ85fLCKZ
      I0fh7UeYodVscDhgo4F+knkkmT4Y6a/T8hJ8v+EpVglAPvYEBl4JUHaSwLWCK+4HQbh1bAByGwWW
      T9HkJe7b6YZSf4YiYfaRs30ftIWuDww+F+oPLDUtefCximr+dKth8B1KuPw41n3hLxAep4ct+mWH
      fLDRLS7hwr7VO4i2rtyWofbyz+Es7dMjFucvFVyAD/i4zeVMST6r9cS88+jQOOjRo0BqkmqPNLEn
      +NjEe9fwHJ/+RExodyFPxq71T+JpBGiTFq8mQP78iiHH/wC2XIHyB+NBmvgrrHk/qcaLf5s+e4O5
      BuQPEu5/TwGsbvg0SLrXLqf1AxMYyDGVJ5xEUaVuTMVkb1c8FQd7UPmhqP49wzhZxmiRRFkEMKUl
      S4o+oE7drAMpCsDZQ0KBOJZLAudvaz2uv7Wbr350GudD+o0M2TKssYxY8gfw2sGOP+GyMZV+1178
      Vya+bCnFYy5IsNvQ908bErCHXewUjkLXoZvYbxqH4P8ABc/UHZYwRW0iwQCG/cWqgq8E+5H2gmtb
      t4a8IdPxKjxoUyZgw3PJ2Thhu3BCoPBFDk3zoFHwh9LVmTzchPLCk0zcpIm4uGWMi1WmAtj+3lTZ
      Bb+g4uCkixdLxY5TGOcorujUjuol93uiQl1+NMjeH/NmaXJfzUKBFxyP4S83ZB+979zX9NSeodUg
      xFUSEIvZQFPNeygDv+BoIr9BaZQMuYy9iYwqCMMrBgQNpawR7sf/ABXmTrOBiu0KPEsjEsYogCxP
      YkqvayANzUL99RMeDKzhunvFxm5WFSDLIp5/inlVB/lQ3+R20xYOBFCoSKNY1HsoAH/bQKXVeqdS
      djHhYIiBNmWdlHJHPoWwfm93tz35Vk6d1LAyz1DNdcgSAx0nOwMQdgWgKO0EV/m43PzqfVOopjxt
      LIaVa9wLJNAckCyTrLvFXi6bP8zEw8acPtopJtQsCfvHNlQedyk/bYrgkJOFg5GTkyzrPGvm+SjN
      GhZSQjBw4sbuU20TQ5+a02weCoaIefKcH2/UOgHayBGVHNe9/A41l+ZjZ3Soi8sKMsroZS0xtyFE
      e0ejaC1bm5vki6HOhdL8dMU8zKwZ8eLbuEqgyIF27qalDq1e20i+LsgaCwzfDswAONmTowAAEj70
      r82pYmuOT+TZ51E/9RTYsezqUEjHcV82CFnjdaHqIXcVBJIpqPB47W1YeUkqLJGwZHUMpHuCLB11
      I0C7i4O2Pf06ZdlWkLcw/NChujHsNvA/lPbSh4x8N4nVT5IQY/UI4y2x0K2ARxuHpZLNbl3VuHa9
      WmdkRdFfduUYuTMaj2hTEzCyVoeoHk+rkcAauuv+HsbqUcUnmOCltDNBJRUsByCOD2GgzbBxh0JH
      3YXmNYIyCxrkcrewKHqyCC1AOePtbIfFXV3y8uXJcU0jX/YABbri9oFkcE6/SvTJcqGdMLqQhyIp
      A3k5RABdwL8tozYDld9UeQp781V+NfpJh5EbPjR+TMB6QlBWr2NjjjgdgKGgyb6cYeY+S2XHuMoB
      jjZxuDSFAFVy3IUKRbewoWCRpw+puNiRQpjMCzxRqHmpd0gReWJANuXAQluQTXdhdn03qUHSopjF
      jEzK3rTlTsA3GhbMh27j3K+kleONYt4l6/LlSvJIxYsxO4/cV4Cqa4obb7Dkk/0DSPoN1mONpInk
      Kny2YfCnuXqqZqAFmyKod9aP4PFjBYgk7cv1N9zB5FbeeBy/pY0OC1cVrB/plKUyJZAoOzHc8mqJ
      Kop7E/c69gT8CwCP0V0jp4XJgROI8PE8sgDgtMYyB/VVhuv/AMxdA0aNGjQGqbxhlRx4cxlIClGH
      Ivkqa4/qPkf1GrnSj47gOQ+JhFVMWRNcoN3shBkYcdgdoUm/31XN6BS6TgplYOL0zqclSTQibGkQ
      kED2js8F0Ujjmx7WtlQX6RSp1GPGZkeJwWDoxtUTjfIhHckgUDRN0aurzxl02XP6qkMUb+TjbY1A
      9Pllh/iAKVYIm2+WBvZXDAF36fjFsg40LtIqKq5mWWPmSMq+iEOOxG7cwX7Q3FFidBK6NgI6tFAD
      DDE5jkKrTzlBt5bbW38gk+3pI0z40CxoEUUo7DXqGIIoRQAqigB2AHYaS+rZrZ2Q2LhEbVDJkZQd
      x5DC6VArDdJff2Fgm+RoIPVvEGVLlGDBebzGC2pWF4YgTRkLLzXypcN8KfZtx+mCACV/MyZQKMjU
      W/6V4Cj8KL/rqr6jPjdKhbyYmaWZidqnc8jn9zs7dvyx+APjVR0Lq/UMlyuQVxowCTyjM1EekbWD
      Ka5uv78aBlj6vlOOMNoiGAuaSOms1xtcmvyRfI4PbXy+ocKGxd3c2X3BTde1bv8ANVcfb7arer9V
      ggDA55283HMokRuLKk7d/b2DEj4OufR+qQ5wMZYSopK70cM0RKE0zjvGwHpc8mgGG7uFvi+HyziX
      LlGS6uWiBjVUi7gbV92AP3E2fx21Afw/kQ5j50UkTBlp4fLZb+WVvMIEhoDtRr25Jm+FOhT4plWX
      KeeMlRCr1/CRQaHA5a2ok9wq/Grbqilo3RX2O6sqH4Yg1X59/wC2gVesdIOfkY7OUUYyCVed4Mrg
      fsIFhBtYMT+4WNN2HE6oFkfzGA5agL/sOBpb8KzASy7yA0seO6j9wVoa2V3oGN2/6j8aajoFTL6R
      CrMcHJXGn3kBVYGNnFsVeK65s2Fo8k9+dTMXqmWm4ZGLe2gHhN+ZwSSEslR2A3NzzyOAQ9DxcYvk
      x4oeYsz2qAyMzftBPYe3JAHJPudcUy+oSRgLDDEzH73lsBSL4VVO4+3cD3s86D7m9TMhVJsCXyHN
      OZEjcDjglQ5IF1zRP499UEXQpMCVn6fMrRsLlgkA3KLsNGFQFmrgK3yeb0wT9JznKt+tCU1kLH6S
      Pfi771QJbtyWutUfVpOqYiqWmXMZm4TyBfb9qIu40edxYAX/AG0DMMqKWOPz1jdXI2tQKbh24PKt
      345rteoBmnw5iGWSbDZbDglngYdwwPeKuQQbHYg99U3SPH+AI3TJdUcOyyfwCqFgQHJpmUephyx9
      9NGMiSESY8xH+TduWv8ATu4/t/toOHVeh4uequ6Hcv2SbKYAj23LTKb7EEf31gH1D+muVhkz+mSN
      5FW0WqLDg17AsK59yBzev0KmIiHbAFhk5YIC3ltd36QQps8kgWO+l7rwbKWDzP4BZ/LyMfeLaxa9
      12sAFZgwH7e+0NoMy+lHhZopP1eRuSOMXKjKw3A/4SAVbSM4Vtvatv3F+Nn8GufLkMqlMmSRpZka
      tyl+EHBIIEaooYHnb7GxrMsiDMxOsYUOQ6nESceXtQKjGQFQ8igczbqUPzRHFXrVfEI8sx5Qbb5J
      PmcgBo2BDBuOwNOK/l/NELrRrzGwIsGweQR769aA1n/WJ95zOpRNIf08UmNEoQN69w810HuNyhOP
      5Xu+Kec8uI3Mdb9p27u11xf4vWVLPNkdGwMXaY8jKm8tQj7aVGdpJuCLAVS/+oqefcPHhhTgdPyM
      pFByp2SFb9Cyuppq3AMSJHkU7gDa0PSFOnLwjtxoHQi1iDNPkFlCtL/7ijntHW0k0BtA9jXrxL0g
      LFF5TbWhASBAF+8qUU7iL4vdwR27jXKboilcfpuwPj7d+Qd3qcpRUMKsq7gk3Vha5FjQdZepGXD/
      AFOXux4258sMNwXd6SzniyKY1SgXyQL0nDx5BA8mF0fEaed2DWlFXJNO70eCKHJruLrVn4j6ZldS
      lWGCcx46F1mlUgofVRiWiNzrXulL2JPILN0rpOJ0rGIjTaossQtySHv7ep29gvJ7AaBN6B9O5Z2G
      T1Mb52WmWUiTyxdhEt245PqLcX20z9d8L4/kFDkHGj4t7T2s/c4IX+q0eAb1Pws3MnjV/Jjxldbu
      Ry0qf1j8sLurn7+Pe+2uWRgYUNS5Lh2HPmzvdEVbD9ikVZ2gUBfYaDNs76ddGkdFGZllmXgqGkDf
      nd5RFe/cDVr0r6Tx4jpmdOy3dlU0km1kmB4ZCy1SsLF80aPtq78S+OGW/wBCq5IUje0bjanP7pWH
      lIQQeCWsfy3euWHl57F5CMMOfUiY058x9t7rB/huSaIB9rBZTzoLP6d9SnlSaPJUrJFJQUkEqrKK
      U1xYIb+1av8AxBFuxpl2O5MbUsZpyQLGw2Ke6o3wa1SeGpMd8ufJitWyYo96sCrB8curhlPKsokj
      BH5B7c6YuohzE/lf4mxtnNequOfbnQU/R5Q+QHUgocSIqeLcOWN/7Bf63+NWHiGRhjyiNgsjKUjJ
      PZ3G1T/YkH+2qXw5NPJNG5+z9IizCx6ZVY8D392/FVr54+nfytsSsXSOaYFULUY4yo7fuuQEC7te
      O2gxlmyOrdS/itOUT+GI4gQ/loe7n7UDcm2sk8Adjpww8THxHXy+nYkTKSIzJn3OeLoEAhXPq43j
      s1cacug+FoP0eMI5JETYJHMUhXzmkALM7D1MDbVzQ3fIFTsWeBV3YWJ5oB27oVjVe1EhmZQwAFWt
      /HsaCl6X4qZGIaCQqar/AJpXBPvtMxVjwbIu6HA+WjB65DKxjBZXH7ZEZb9vSSNrj8oSPzrnk5rF
      fVhTP/l/gmvzzLX/APeqGHwqQgXE8uOBSP8Al5oZSD23A3LtBPPrCHv71yDTldKgkUJJDE6qbVWR
      SAfkAigfzpJ6n9OYse8rp26HIjJdRGAfMJ/YVZgmyuAvpqyb5vXOPrLYbyCKJztb+PCxBMAHZw5Y
      M0DWSHpq7EKQQH7AzEmjWRCCrCwRoFnpniWOd0w8uGTHyim7bLsG4gd42DEMff03XvWuPXcGeVJP
      LUHKhG0MaJkjJ3xuOKEiOoYEqaKsADu1Zdd8M471OPMimiB2Swkl0vvS8hl5spRuux1Q+G+sSvB+
      sndJHxjLCzoVHngfbYBIDEhGFGqY8aDn4mhOf0XzZQgyYU3uV7xSRH+KAV3FSCp4FngCtXHg/PHU
      +mKclFfzEKScWslCtw/r8ftYEdxrlPFGZpYUljVOpRPQQAkSom2Rt1bWBQrwfdPyarPo3G+PDldP
      kfc+JkEAEAEJIoZTwexbeRoGDwB1Ey4mxozG2O7Y7KRX+EdoNXxa7TXsSQOKOmXWd9MysiHr+VCI
      R5M8UchYEi9gCbwD6d3q2sBRISxZFa0TQVHi7NMOFkSL94ifYKu3IpBXuSxAr86VfA+E0mbNOxGz
      EiTDhVWBUEKrStQJUN9osUasECtXH1KgeXAeGNFZ5XjjG79pZwA4/wAynkfBo+2jrhODhpFiAB2Z
      Yo93O55DQJJYGyx3FqagCaOg+YrjKzWmcMFwdyItWC8gG5yRxvVRtCgWoc2bYqsvoHTlIyJ3jeN8
      uQmRWNGkHlJVGwCihu4Nse3YLXUxNiDF6fi5AR2QvMwCDaoa5JgzggFnaub7335079JkBhQhmYV6
      Xc2zgcBzxXq7/wBCNB2VI4Y6AVI0XsBQUAf+NLnTsig3UskOvm7EhiYHdErMFRdt0JJGZb7d1BNL
      xa5eOMgI4n/ghg/8Mkb9p7F1blLHK1R5B1AyOombLigVSI4mZ5mZRRIA8kKb/czBgR/LX40Fp1Tq
      cUEZaZlXj7SRbfgD3PtpGlSbqUpghXGhixqEs3kiWpWCsUg3eiwppnZfccc0Pf1DzMXAVskTVlbS
      oV55S7K5ukXedtsByoFD3A41UfRqfJ/SP5ZEhnmaQku22ANd2zKd0pPO0A+xYixoGWb6eQSNuycr
      JmaiKaRUUX8LGqir9jY5Os+8aeCsjEljycWMPEiX5sLLGybBd8jaKUcE7rI73V8et4GfPmSLJkSr
      5TgGLF375E/dIOdzutrZo8H0jaKFflQZGTGcPIyp8bZIP4ckfpYTSqp3lO1OUu/TZWlXmg1jwp1e
      GSaMOyiebGhyQCNrSM6vHI1dr2pHaj4Hxq98SdVWJCl07KfUTSxjsXZjwAOSBdtVD3rL/HXTMpIc
      CXDJ/ULlSJERttQP4Ua7SOwSMbvYHcT308dBwVy5WyMomVoajjjYUilRteUJVFnYNRP7QCK3aCv6
      Z4gTHyESQi57O1RR52BuP8rigPcOdt+7lYSZmkZR5m2OME96BY/3JJ/2Gq7xn4Wjz4fLc0Vsq1Dg
      kfJFjkA2tHj+oOU53U87J6vj9Kn3BIWNPQ81l2FhIzAbSQApsAAlboXWgkeJusHExmxCGZFmnCRc
      lHVZSW8wjnyo1dFC9rBuwK1beGEzuowIY+o+RsVVH6aEFEKDszEhWa+6xihYBJFar/qLhFIJI5F9
      afqwsinuspXIUcm91KynnsG77hpZw/FUjpHix5rYeNDGFJjpQXCFmRHoAWQfU7FmY8WNA+9R6/1X
      pOwZZjzYGavNRSstlgKI+yzYoWPf4GnDwj4xx+oIzQbxt4ZXAUg+4q/b39tZ94Y6vkODh5AbLx5o
      0G3IZfMVpUEixswo8qym6JBI7c1x8BZawdaaK2jSdGTyPMDsskYsbxQIAQMAxF8C+/Iaf1PoiFxk
      RRKMhLKtwu78OdptT7+/J5Gk/pufJFKrRr5MOQ1SRFfLMcpPOyyybiRYv0uCaIqtaTrD/FeZjx9R
      lwcnzFgyNu5j5YALGtysq/tNGpBX3ggbiWDTs3rz4ssceUlxSsqR5Cdg7GlSVO6WeA4JBPfbxa/1
      pIMDqKzsrCLMNTNuIRDsKg7QKa+AQe3DEjbqzxcUZPTJ8PczyRiTHclqPmRigQeSAfS4BugwHtqm
      g6kuf0PdM9MIwfNVg3lso3JKxVgQQw2seKYMTQ5AdOsZkGN5cOBW/DH6po46KvEz7Zx/q2OzivcC
      tc/Ek8sUkHVun7ZIiduRCAA0glKC7/mWgRfYkkWGOvmB1NZcfp/UHBdEMsWTJIFLRK6sjXSLcYkV
      bauxs+51W+AMZt3UejyyIJIuYHjIO2N727Qb4QstXZXfV6Bm8Sbv+IdNn2lYTvVpd4X7kLKrKRfd
      RVfLA17uw0gdV6Qj9IYtGkk2MpkFIy/xcewfTZNkqR8MD2o6bfDk2/FhkpF3xq9IKUbwGof76CF4
      hxzJkYK8FFmaRlJ77IX2mvfa7IfwaPtpf8U5izdUwMdRZhdppG3AgKqMAKDFlIarLKF7c+2rrqlD
      qmEa5aHIW6//AEmq7/BPb27+xUusM8mV1DMBowQpi+VZ/wDdYNJ3G3eU21V2T3ra2g+eHMn9RKsr
      xXkZc0m2TYgIx4CFaQOhG5PtRC1myCLAB02eNupfpsZEi8tWldII1Z9n3kClpT2W+1duOdVn08yE
      nlnyIYwuPEkeNjm73JFbMR8Dc1GrB2gCtpuD9WPExxo0kUgpG/s5DNMBcaelhaL97ggg+lfc0Hvq
      DSPgQYaACPJmbGYmgVjR2RqFDczqhJNe5q+LkQrK+bkSQp5i45jix1Z28oNtAlfhiisi7l7brJFc
      83HQukf8niGdSk0WMqm2ooxRfMO4DhiRRI7c1ql+neVL5+ZEhWbFD748gG7dvuTdt/i1x/E/Fc+w
      UP1QgXJzMfFyXlWNiXEZZNr+UrHam31CVwdu5yBRoc3ph8B9bafp0YheFZlRW2sQBEhc8bV7Rqql
      V5s7RZB51BkzD/xRvOkQHHxnKMzt5Yd6G6RqCxp+1QByd3crqp8B4/6Jsbcf4crzYzeknzTuMsUi
      7V5j2s9sxIAHBrQWvU8nGn8iXPWWDzmRFLQq0MjKW2Mu5CyF1ojdRraP2mpv/BlRoY4oyuQxWwoQ
      COMEbpXA4ogFFUkn1cdmIZHx4MmVWdopRCwaJAwYKxX7yP5xbBfgWe54j53WmETOlF5W246qNzOB
      QL7eCQPU/HG0D50EDosJGZl4zRyMtiXz2YEDzvuRbO4Kdm2lFUvezy0Y2NHCm1AFUWT/AOST8k9y
      TydVPSmb9fmKQa2QFSfcVIP9rVv++rLrL1C/yw2D+rkKP+50EwHSZ4plgVhnUBPjF1RgaLKKEofj
      kKpdgp/lv+jmBpUbAhyIGicVT5TGqIY3LBJd+wEnb+mgjeJukwvI5PO5Szs5JA3JalfYbUgIBqxu
      J7nVJ0/wnOigRectxAVv2KdpO0MoAUP8HbYFcjTb03pxkjjZ23b4ow5vn/BdTXHcmS/76m9a6t5I
      XYBI5ZRsBsgOdu6hztB/8HQKPRxH03+JnFYS5PkL5rSFzsBfc22jMTdEk3fHN3m+e8efkzeVCsUu
      RkRujsHWVI1JjLKxBpn9J2jgc964c/G3iM5EKSQRSO5jiZREVLwmTckobv6l3IKI4YDtzpB8EYck
      qJlzr53mZqIRJ+8csx7fbe4/BIK9zRDZvAPVZp8BWMnmywyNGWNfxRGeLNn1FSPUP3f30vfU6FJY
      sXqcUd+VIVkDMY3KtaNHR9JbfwVbuRt5Bo3X0gwhHgEhSPMnlayKLAOUU/P2qO/Ng67+POjI+HLt
      U15iysEYAqwIBkW+NwFPtPpNG63E6Dj4H6qk0xkhMZiyII5AUNU8R8twVI4O3YO5IC0TQW6PoHSD
      D1TKwC/lwsjSwFG2vskbcy8inVZL72RRBtXI1cRxRYuZiRpQRpJE2If8OSSIswPF7D5Vrf8AMfYC
      q/x5054uo4mXFv5EnpX/AO5EvmgKD+6SNJE7gc37mwneJegvj9PyEizDEq75Ab2HZt9aWi8AHlSq
      8cLRHBUvESjH6h0bNx1ZBIsUUlEsmxwoRfTYFhm44ugQDRIdfqbjHI6cDGsbAvG22Tcu5W9O0MOU
      ZtwXceAC113Cx9W8aTbgyjHjXZPCBZJkQXXlsqEho91GwTyQK+QbPGStCRMkhRZLWVBQEp20m6Rr
      WOgKuhfa9TfAGG8WFHHLE0ciWrbq3PsJXeSCb3Vd+4o6ofqR1MIyq0xh2jeVZN6TIvLBaI2ydx6i
      AeORwwcegZ4nx4pl3U6ggsu0n817XoPPWXhhU5coUGFHp2NBQ1WL7Cyq86yUeItvQMzJi3rK87Hd
      I24q0kgX0N7lU7cnb3s1rTfG/TmnxJIwbFWU/wDuVyEJo+knuNpv41gPWZwOjLjShUeLPVSFkLlV
      EUnJ5PA3UAODRI0GpeAstMDon6h922i+/azA+kAEKBax2u0fNbiRuOl/wf0pupZ6Nkbmj6dZbgFJ
      MmaRpZQD22q7UB3pFvvpm8d4EkeFh+UgWKAxGVlcDaqbQqBTwUY8MxIocncLGjpn6fB6CJghdWhE
      77fTveQB/UUApdxCdq2gA8aCu+pfjNnhyocUboYAY8uQ8C3IURx8jc/Jujx/m7Fo+nPU45Ol4pUL
      FUQGw8UQCLo87W2lgfcc6WJMVcbw+4nu5o3lndogpUycUEIAEhtUQGvn2rXRMNcaXomFOkcgWOaW
      RuQqSRRLtkPsQLK23uQeKrQdcw5MXVsRpVXZN5i350lsFj3lnX/C2oNwCgAWw5PJ1mniSQHElTHl
      3pPnv5CIrKxEnBsA0VahQbkjmhY08+JvE8ydViEg3QNEISioxEfnFt1uaqTYEcir27RQ5Ok2TwfJ
      EuNDTi8oiwdtWwRdzD9+1T2s23psDkL3w6/M+TiwrjSyxlkKY4qHHicq8i2Axkf17VoliEBIAJ1p
      XRU2xrsCx+vyEo2IooAQwXjgEo392UntWlvrsITq8EcA2KuNHGy9owq5MbAKv4UP244q+Dq4kyZR
      hiRY0YvGW9QBBOQWkKMNx7/w097MgrjQe/p4Gc5WTITvlmYAXwER5PLodqpjz3Jv40wdYkFwKf3z
      KP8A4hn/AP8AGqnoOTDipKssqIqyBFZ2A37Y41NX3Jk3ji7Yn31Wdb8WoM3FCwZLxRli8qwybELo
      VU2QAas38A/1oHvSdgJIXlTiNUypeT7xyLIzH/SXojtyv4rV+OvY1gefHZBIG7mh3Nfyj57aWIM9
      WysiFzw+WYkN+xxA7AUL7MWF3fPPYaC2zc/9JsgjjLfwXfdXH8ERqAefuYEV+AfjS71bp4gzcvKQ
      rEYlimPw6mOZST8ASUx9uCSLN6nR47ZAVvMvzen0oBHDral7He/Mr441zhy453GW67o8nARPLkAK
      7jI1IR8sX2kdjQ0FX17DWF4mwQ4yOoZCs6bq8vegkZxxQ27CxH7jffVN4q6aLTBhilYJLL5YhZVu
      SaNyNxJACq6SPRPsq86lt1RsbEl67LUkk5UY0Yvau7cqcXx6SbA57/Nap/DfVv1WdD5qM+O00qR5
      VBWd5PUjkbPT2VPTXLC7NWGx+HIUXGiEYIXbdMKazy24Vw267Hzel7xbYOSgkCJJiyGRGApiqNtc
      GwQzAMCeeIu3YhnlTy4iF3cA8gWwvu35Pufc/k6R+pmSNcOXIkhyJXLQxzxowDLJDIS7KCVoBQe9
      EF+PgOvV8KLJfpmbDSSTzwuzj96pE70RdbtoK33/ANtW31GMi4ZmhK+ZCwdA3ALG0Xn25cH81XF6
      zvwJ1hpZul4USDy4GlnZxZUVG6MqntQeRuRxytAChpz+oP8AHaLHjkYS7tyrf8MsjIQj0LDMG/8A
      iWNGuAsPGSJF0mVZdtJCBzZXctbL/G8L8e2kn6rZhbM6WhK7ROnmKb4a0IraNwHq7g82nHp01/Ub
      JZlxMNNhmyZxSsTW2JS8hquV4VTY7NfBAIVPrXFG+V0+NfTOZUA9JIdGY0L7EK6jgg1vsdzYMv1D
      6MciXHVMgRESBirKjXwQoUPxbVVH0tto0Ty2dGxPLjCKGVQAFRgPTQo1tNBTV0OBZ9uAq+PcrGdh
      E8InlSMzxxUf43kuC6KQeXWr2jnuKIJBdMZ9yq3HIB4Njkex9x+dAu/UKedMRv0+/c3pPl/4gv3T
      1AkjnhQWPsPfWRdXjU+H5t8RZ45kPmsQWLmQK+5t5twCV9u/atfoMjSb0Dwz5U06GJDhkqUEoDO0
      gfcW57RhlBUfJuux0C91HNmm6ZmLNJG5x3Cq6ttClI4iQQDwRJu5PAAJ7Vp0z+kjLw0ijlZI5Cjl
      l9JKFt5A4sEg0DwV4PcaWuhxy4HUJ8XI9UXUZJJYpjR/iULiP/QLFgDihfJ136lkNidPlxVDA4Sx
      MG774VlHI5+7y0II9yO3NaD79WsNR007PT5RUxoE3fYQ3C3XCqSWPCrvP5GaQeJRN1vp7z5XnRRL
      6pm2Il7WZjx6QqtXck+m77a3jCmhyIkyAAySR2pcVaPz2PYMKNH8Xr87fVHw5jRBJsNZPLcvTsyh
      GVavykrcU3N9/Ykkiwd2g2XqvSE6pGwaMxRpKGhkZSC/80gX/N2ViO1kd71G610xWzsGJo2MInaU
      G+A0UACEjueRe7tf9eeHgTxfLJF05J4ywyYHqYG/XAWDBhVDcoBH53fGrvr5CZuFKzhQXkjCGhy0
      bMW3EX+wAAV3N3xoKnrmCv6yTJ/fJshjaxahfS20dyd0xu7HoA9wNevEHU4MSByCFSGVmIJ5by4S
      EoX7SmJFHyo9+dSM1FmyTsU7Y54o2NkAtuGRJtHbgpGCR3twe2lrxThifHxVnvacuXz/AE7WaJch
      2cfhRtDnnsprmtAjeAvGGFBkjKyopXnsrEsSKwjDWDZZ97SNuYlqsljd8a1g/VvpWzcZ3BHdDDJu
      u6qttX/f/wAaz7xl4O6m+YkWPCrYpP8ADVQgiRbIAYcdlon5+SdLvUvCEkfUWxH2M5KdvZXeNBRP
      H7uL9VGzz3Bn8efUvp+bEYhjzeYpqLIO1TET9xBDbh2rb+7+2pv0q8Sef5YkRDJh/dLwN6SKY1fn
      1B14U1wQR8DUL6c+Fuq4+aqTwkYyFlfeVKFSf2C+b79vz31Y4XhODHz8h0Ux1lLJGi8DyYUE0gof
      sLhQFP8AKtDQP/SYwr44NABMmMDuf8Va5+KTn540ieGkdukTxs1x4ucyxujcoiSAgkH2UsTz2Ug+
      2nrpkfly4ccpHmDGlYjeeDuh3muxFt9x5+O51UeFsJIun5izKqxvk5RlFighlZWN/AQXz8aCh8WQ
      rL1Tp/TEtYYB+orjhjIdi9q2itvbsffU3q3hpceSWdmZcdFeONFoJD5jecHAAsbZQlEG1KA9q1B6
      H1iKbrWLkxSB1fDMEjewdH4v4LHbXsdwA768fVrxdNEGxfKUASBmbcpDINjLQJ3br3Gq4IGgd4fG
      MDdOfOibzFjVvu9JZkHqHx7HkcfGse8eeL540mxw/lo/EcJi5VJAC0iuft/cgHwz/jTv4e6McvE6
      fHCGixI/VMnG8SKd4DAimjYkfkccUTWW/UbHfI6plABtquI0J4VdsfC9jSgKeB8+16Bt+hOVEqZB
      lOxF3FW3UUJAB4HNlT35+0/jWjeG8FZpJZ2laQSqjoSu0hSnprgEEbmaiLUuR7aUejeAGx4sWKMK
      ZSjTZBYUzAWFSvcDfVX3APbWpSSlYnnWMs/l7vLB5JVb2j8nt/toF/HgjbOysycgtiqqIhF+UoVm
      8xb93V2BI+CL4Oqvp8uHl9YmDFWaGOGWAFiGV2DeYyi/5ViDAWOB7k6idc8XvD1DHVDHPi5agekg
      uFfgFebO1ifTXYqO+rTw79PcSHGdIpC8r0f1JCmRHUCipq1IoWugj9W6bLJnqWjRytsv+pQdsi8i
      pCnobkXtU2KBV56dGVjUMu01yLv/ALgVfz/5PfSZ0PomZEYGzJhJMkrXIgNMpIT1f5nBU3xQSvbl
      80Bpb8V9DOVXmSzLDGpPlwGnkZrHJAulFVVfcxPYUya8TfaeCeDwDRPHtz30GcQ9LfNgk6fkSt5+
      K6yQylkMqKbEbOUahMpBuu4A55NNGPmLkQTgBTNCXhfzOwKtwzf5SAsntwR21V9V6bltPDNH5caY
      x3+Uiks60w2tJ2ZiCSEAoHkliV1W9X67j4edjZolrFy4G83i0A3K0biv3FpDfyC3xwFp4EyfPgmw
      5wsggYJXlFA8bKGQFSTY2kc3R/Pc0H1YxgcKYjb5i7PNcn0orMFWJKU29MaFcBmY0WW5ks8vT+pi
      Z/48HUCoaTb6omG5Y4xQAERLRqNx737knTrndP3sHoN5dskZ4UyVw7fNe3xZPJC0H5k8M+IngTyV
      engl8/HfcaDKr7onBP2Ot8KASzd+eNn8cypmdKg6gvpMfl5CtfEfYt7ckdq4N8fINL1bwMP1vlRr
      upIskttUecyySiZOB+5ZFFexYH5OpXheCWXoefjhVjeKXKRFT7BRL7VJHCbiQG7juCCBQNjYQxkw
      13Fz+o3ySAcO0wcM5HsGklFD2sew0reLZ5WjYQcvvmVChFhxksykXxZkSJCL5DsNXeLkfqOiGcDe
      WR50UuTsZZGljWxz/DIUV/krXnF6RBmozJKSksUrLtO1l/USxzxuLHDqy8NXpYfjQJXhfxSMiADL
      zBhRQtuMSsNx8lwQnrjsC9voBPwABxqk6711JOo+bflmbfIl2SCoiEG6qG1jjIx2kkb2XuL07Z3Q
      pWKrn9JXKkWNVOZA8ZZvyyOFth78H8fATF8QuJ4srFTB8nGDqX/SPGVBUFi0Ya2NC/SaBJ7DQMXX
      fqRjhIczEnZJpFHmwGQFE7XuXaW3/DKpHckc6++AMqbNyY8nIIT9R5gRRyTDCVZ+Tz/EkMYLVW2N
      lAFivOD0/Gynjy/+HzdQlkAPmPF+nxwORtVTwaNcvuu/u4oNPhzw/LDLL1DqMqK/lNFHGn2Y0W69
      ooAFqAHA9ve9BbeHyMnIysooQhC46Bh96RguZBzRVzKar2UXz2pegxN+jyMK7Zv1Cb+CylpJY08z
      2YnYvqod1BHvptlZcXE4basMQAZlsAKALYCuPc1XvrP/AAh1l/1MmQVZmng3hQoAZEyZXYxju/om
      9vUGUhgNy2FV9LvCL464+cm9yxEcsW3skhpm5PDxOBdftW+/GlXx5gyv1dTOC8KTRI1sWWjRUci/
      UvHvdGzwTrZJMw48eZ5KqBFOGYdtpkZJJCeOUZX337EuOKFLWP4XXNC/8QPlS5UwyFiUj0qpdkS6
      oybSQexrcR2Ogu/DHiaNYsmaQ7Yo9hU0b2iK2Ug9njKspHel550leG+jrN1Jn3ncyNLFu7MSoUgN
      Xbbtb5P9jq88WlZc/G6XHGed7vJfDK8MkcisRzvAZWs9yR7kW3dLxv0eMIiY2eINJ25ZAeT/AKqO
      2+3A4A4AXZiV2SQHlSaI9weCP6X/ANwNY94x+pr4E0kWIgkikaRgXsGN1kdJQvyhdSwHBFmjRG3Q
      cfrixYmRIx5ikmPB/a0rFG59trD/AGPxr8r5TmbzciR7laQs3AFlySTQHANk8AAUR7jQbl9HPDOP
      lYU2VlQrJJkyyCz+1d1+jm0O6zYo8KfYa1uGIKABZoAWe5oVZ/Osu+i3UMkY2OjNFLjMGQNGfXDI
      NzhJBX8oPq/MYr3Oq6DnLEGq/Y2Ofca6aNGgNGjRoPh0m9OwoXlyMPJhj9YDxpZI8oHhe21XRm3F
      UNDep97Lnpb8S5qx5WDuFKZZA0hHpQGFwAW7As1AD3/20CrmROnT8jp8SzySwyquOZFZmChrSXhS
      dqMj7QQB6V7KQdOHgjrjZuFFkOmyRgVkWiNroxVxR57g65dT6SRn4+XCSGIaOcWaeII7Lx23CTbR
      4NMdYt4X8ay4vU2xllWPEbMd33MNoU7lb1GvTzu47lR37kN4x8TdPLOfdFhAI7hCxY/0Jav+m+eN
      K/hmMthdQhDGSQTZClWA77QFG1ftQgCl77a0wz+IonxZsnFdMgRoxqN15oE9yaHa+f7apMmV+ndE
      3KjmRIAW2jcwdx65DyLIZmc8i6/Ogzn6O9UyJvN6ZKzqhjEkSkfYjiy3PdaZWC1TFubFgsfRZYYV
      TGaGNrUviF3fzDDJyQGALMARbRiiP5aA1f4vTIYZH6xHRQ4UaxAitoAu2+FoR8nsN10BrL8HGfN6
      LOwAfIwcm4pFNOquyszWD9otjXYBfcqDoGrO/wCM4xWXZ+rxCppcSZhw3Y+rcWoVVDmh8m6Q9f6f
      u3T5PUYMhTwZMaJSm7gllSPa+6gNzergVWrbwR4ulkR4hIIs2KxKkikoxXgysopqcn1FOVb1EEMx
      0yjx7IvpyOmZMhqxJiKMiJ+O6uK78ijyPfvoKjC8cQfp2EM/UclxQUx4qjbQHsFVSvzZ9+/I1f8A
      S8XqOWIZp2SBFF+U8Su7sDauwIqNh8Kx+bB41xPjPIRVY9OGMjdv1EwRmJ5pIo43kd+b2hb0p+OP
      qMUWSLe1GiVNxySWOI1St8UNUzO58xuQAAbAMOD4gm6mz4eyMpG295kb0yiGRaj2kHaJJFZbsgqj
      1+LroeHG2HGkgMUsTjcoN+VKTtYKf5WNsPw4PHGsl8A+K1xcXLzZS36h3UKvZWC7Co/AoFQAKoV8
      aY/BviFEgME7eZaSy9Q3Ky7A/lRo17SGYKNu0EXTEdhYMvhbqiyvlPKojixgYZvMaw0flq6O1jt/
      iEj28w+2k7qmZkK7ywnZj4mZEGV2tkVpgFcH2sgowN2CCTd6ZvDYOB0SSecjzpo2lCseT/CCwx0f
      cRqi188cnvafT7oKRdPjOTbPktHM/mdw52mNf+kqtfnQefCHTpIJkbMdTk5CyyBTyyBSg2g/hGVT
      /pHfUTrniCCN2WeZRJEssPfl/wBQxEQIH7v4Y5/1HgarfqF1Bi+LsnEWWs08aOeAoZywJofaPJjV
      jXCyWe+qOTw0kmXjRPNHJ1GZn/USq5ZY0UsxVRQtnjYLbdgOPbQd4vBWVPBP1D9UYpG3oUFbWghb
      7bYgJKClhrAB5NWTrt0bwREMiV8rFaSCRV8qRSVeMURv8tDeyyDxZQ7DVeoPGUsbsnTYYlfGhCrk
      AMPQpHoj216u6s3alrvem3aO9c6CN0/HREGwJ6gCSgADGgN3HyANStGjQGjRo0Bo0aNAaTfqPhTz
      RLHijdOWUruJ2IFcWSB7sSBZ7LuIIo25a+VoFzwx1Veo4nmSRgW7I6bibMb0b4HpJW9p4ING7I1m
      H1X+m6RxNlwqzyMbkbcQq3uZm28mydsaqLstybrV/wBUfG6V1tcmR3SPLhfdfKLI0qW3wq1yT8n8
      60NGx82FW4lhYhhYNEowINH4ZQf7aD8w+CfEkuIs+NuYLNw8YQ79yMOATwtruuweFI4ux+ns3FGT
      jPExoTRFSVb+daNN/fvrBPrP4bWHJkzEsGRrdewO4lRR7+oIxP8AqGmv6R+PYI+nR487EzRyNHHG
      is7upIKmq4AL7e9AAaBvkwpJ+j+TMBG8iVIFb/NucA/BUN/bSD9NSuNkv02cV+ohQSKTySFeNloG
      r3k2Qfb451qPiqIsiLsZkVtzqvAYEFNjN7IQxLH+VT86y/q3S5YBj9X9JnRIpHUqQC2RKzEX91cl
      R8A8jQKP1H8POkwyY73Ozhn7bnjkkBJPZW2iMDtuJNc96fp31H6hFx5wcVRDKLP9WWnPxZbW4YCY
      /UunyyoA0bpIjqeWDbd0jX7Nvoj8c+4AxLxB4Oljm2qqkCBZyQeNjOVZz8BTwePa9BF6p45y5idr
      JDYAPkJsah2G/mSvxu5118FeGWzZAv3FroG79Hr/AP5Kjp7USvzrzgeGXMR3oqv5iqpNkgMWRrA4
      oEWD8j860jwi8WBGMgwlQ0nkbgeRcyxg8nt6ZAx72o+dBy8AfT5t8WXlMBjQtI+x2vYY/SoPttJO
      /d7BAPfUz6kdPSGsfHFPmTRQuwerijG9Vr4pwCb52/2F7jSNHG/T5pSpKNEHbhd1NGp/DPvgf82T
      8gI3T8uTP65gbuHgRDKNwovGx3lPwfSSp7euuKJDR/HXTv1WTj4SkbNhMoDUQm+NeDR9QsEe/b5v
      TFjwK4zIl9JDhRX7agjKEfFcEfkaRvE0D4nU5M13Z4Csch4soI5BvUEcUuwkg/IrlddPF3Vch+oH
      G6TkqJ5oFaQgKyqUcBSbUgWjmyBdKv8ATQVeN1JcmaScxMMhJFMTIOUOTAm6UA8ErHZYWSNikDvT
      10vwliYCCbdTq2+TIcgM59YO49gCJGFCgOPgag+CvCTQSvkZLlpEpYwDSRgxL5hFAbiSSu5roLQr
      Vf416vk5rvhdP8qRFSKSSWywO5yPLsAixSvdngHg8jQNHgNw+GkpRkaV5ZGDqVa5ZWc8HmuRX4rT
      FqF0cDyUK7trKGUMbKgiwt9+O3NnU3QGjRo0Bo0aNAaNGjQGjRo0EbNwlkBsANtIV6BZLHdbB599
      Jw6fP0mAGCWTIxkd3eOQbnRCvZXvhQwuyD3PzYetfGUEUeQfbQIvV48TrWJJFuLPENxRC3ok9aqT
      wN3KuAOR712Osh8SdBl6N1D9Sg3wRSRstmgzMhKpV87SDx7LXzrZup9GkxSr4cgQCNvSy2HaNmlV
      WPHBV5Rfft764fUfw0mViyMxBUP5hodvQsZIP4UE3oOf0u8VjPXJDkNIJNzDuNrrQ9q22rKB7gA/
      u0zeIenRSQTLKu9WC2n820ikH+o8f9Wvzd9OuuZGJ1KKBiwD5CRyx2ACwYxjdxztLGqNWAeaGv01
      HmJIQtEkO39vKaix/G6q97r4sBk/QOp/8O6lkYWW3l4sgOyuF3SKiFyP5f4dAntvB/fp4zumRLmY
      8WzcjYssLg8ho2KXuFc01f2dtKX1B8H5Gf1EmIfwRCFaQMBsewxHPJNCLtxV9jr5Ji9QyMCJgu3L
      wmjMJKsDMg2rbfuG5o5CR7jb7NoIvSujFQuNM1vFO4kJoEFJC4P+mWOVWAPAJHsOGbGx8afInwgF
      aISurqLoB03N343iWP299383PfDijy82Gdh6Mjp6OyezFj8/6X/7DXTpWEOn4r7yxnMkxB7tLTPN
      S+xYxKf7roK3xpkRxIssiLktDG8U9obBEZphwQrMHeieDdBhbWg/R/pc8jZWftDSiM+XzXmMCrOO
      3dvT6hyGPPuDd53g+fqLZjxZAjlEhSmvbMrxJR3A3yAa+4EbeODpgl6iIscSQxfp2SNysVBdk0QC
      yw8HafMQqygcEpu99BViWDq/6qfGMxRloxMvB2eUz7FHO5xa/k/B0xfSfwQmBj+a3qyJh62uxQPp
      Cf5SKPyeL7a94WXBjRfqV9OXPiqVgc0f4aBVG37hZ2KT/TXnpMOZnSO2S3lQpKV2RueWikApWFHb
      SG+P3mqINBy8aePBGuTj4+NNOyKUaSKmRC0bGyVJKsvHDAE8121efT/wxFgYiRRrTOqvKbJ3PsUM
      eew47du+rDo/h3GxS7Y8SxtISXYXb2S3qJPPJNX2s6tANAAa+6NGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDR
      o0aDzIgIIPYiv99I+FgvhIR/EmgLNHJBxSlyx8xeLKylgzAkhS5qgCA9a8uoIIPY8aDG+peDcPL6
      lDkiYojqzP5RFRyRgsTvII+4Emx/L86iw+Mo+m5075DStE8X8BLLH0KuzddeqQMzEnsT/toUPgmJ
      IcaFFRRG4abaoHn+n1Emu5cI/wD01YGlFvBEc2X1NHBcpGjQEgHymYyMFF9+FWjX2sR+dBqPT51l
      iVxVOtkfk/cD+bu9K3U5Hx8t2JeVp8eXyoVrbcZQBF4+4rVljVk1QOkvw712fp+bsy5T+jbGE6gi
      /L8+WMbQbohXfkj2vTL4Z8d4ufmoUPISVEU912kM8h4+1lVK+KIOg4eIetjpuFi58VTRrBHDGhBQ
      kMAUc8WPQOVr/wA659Dx8jMiyI2BBhMXlFjy5WIq/HsssTsm6+CW+Ob/AMfdJhyosfGkU+X50ZIU
      cBeVHb9oLLfwDrn1Hq8UMkE3KrHGVZQ3JUxMyqR7kNHQu+W476DxndVjhKxLSrNJuUnulJFtYf6X
      PIPZVb+WiseK+u4mbkQ4+4vu8l3WIF2jkjL2lLzuIej8bTdVrhJ4Yys9svLmPkSCOod/IWNrkKEA
      ghwCbN8WnwRpx8F+C4saAybSuTkKGmk/cC9F1X3UXf8AT80NBM6JiDKCZcsKoz0xUkMw2JsVdwFF
      QTI1jg2DpmA15hiCqFUAKoAAHYAcAD8a96A0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjR
      oDURcBBMZwKdkCNQHqCm1v39NtX+o6l6NAt+IPCmLO0MkmOsgitdnNbG5PpumpqaiPbjkDSL1LwD
      H0z/AJyB/wD2pIWUikUyQlFfvxbhAfy3fWvah9X6es8MkD/bIpU/3Hf+2gyYdZ6tkLGMaNfMErpA
      xUBGhDgCVg3Hp2XY+VIHOr/wf9OTFMuZlSPJkEHeGI2qQ9jaAK2mgf7D500eEoD+mg8wVLCjQkey
      lWCsO3I9ApvcUffV9oPhGvujRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDR
      o0aA0aNGg+Vr7o0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aA0aNGgNGjRoDRo0aD//Z
      "
           id="image18" />
</svg>
```

Comment: вы бы человеку пояснили бы что означают цифры `viewBox='-97 -76 400 400' ` а то он сам не сможет и объяснение не кудышное